# What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors

Are there any  [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editors for [PGF/TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ)? Perhaps something similar to [LyX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX)   but for PGF/TikZ?

If there is no WYSIWYG editor for this tandem, is there one perhaps that allows the user to easily generate PGF/TikZ templates?

Alternatively, how can I most easily generate PGF/TikZ code from a visual conception? Do people mostly code their PGF/TikZ graphics from scratch?

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex)

Comment: There's an extensive list of tools that generate Tikz/PGF code at [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/). The same site gives nice examples ofcode generated pictures [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/code-generation/)

Comment: Related mentions also in [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex)

Comment: Some related ideas, [tikz pgf - Can we show all the nodes' name in slightly gray color next to them? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651540/can-we-show-all-the-nodes-name-in-slightly-gray-color-next-to-them)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is [`ktikz`](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language) (also available in the `qtikz` version), which seems not only run on Linux/KDE but also on Windows.

> Version 0.10 is released. This version is available as an Ubuntu package for Lucid, as a Debian package for Squeeze and as a Windows installer (a patch release 0.10.1 is available). For Linux there are two versions available: KtikZ and QtikZ. KtikZ is integrated with the KDE4 platform, whereas QtikZ has the traditional Qt-only interface.

I personally use `latexmk -pdf -pvc` to keep recompiling my TikZ diagram file after every saved edit. I use a dedicated file for every diagram which uses the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class (which I wrote just for this very purpose). If you use a PDF viewer with auto-reload like `evince` then the changes are shown directly (after each save). I had issues getting `latexmk` reloading PDFs in the Adobe Reader.

Comment: I can confirm QTikZ working on Windows.

Comment: FYI: It looks like the development of `ktikz` stopped three years ago (although the source code is available, so hopefully someone picks it up, e.g. on GitHub)

Comment: As of 2018, ktikz seems pretty active again.

Comment: QTikZ runs in Windows but it has to be configured manually for use. TikzEdt autoconfigures if you have MikTex or TexLive installed.

Comment: The link is broken; perhaps try https://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz.

Comment: No, the link is not broken (although it's HTTP so susceptible to MITM etc.) ____________________________________________________________________________________________ As far as I can see this is not real WYSIWYG, only **realtime preview**?

Answer (score 23):

There are many programs that can export Pgf or TikZ code of diagrams or pictures generated there. For example

- [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/) is a geometry software that can export nice TikZ code.
- [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) is a diagram design software that exports Pgf code.
- [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is a vector drawing software (similar to Corel Draw) has a plugin to export TikZ code

A full list of this can be found in the [TeXample page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/).

As Martin Scharrer said, there is also [kTikZ/QtikZ](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language) which compiles TikZ code in realtime and previews it in a window. It works under KDE and also in Windows.

Comment: Using external tools which export to TikZ is something very different then having a WYSIWYG editor. Usually these tools generate very low-level code which can't be changed very well.

Answer (score 22):

May be [Tikzedt](http://www.tikzedt.org/) (works on windows and linux) is what you are looking for.

> TikZ/PGF is a pair of widely used languages for creating vector graphics, in particular in Latex documents. There are a couple of editors assisting in the creation of TikZ code. However, mostly one has the choice between a text editor with preview, with no WYSIWYG capabilities, and a true WYSIWYG editor with a TikZ export function, without direct code access. Combining both direct code editing and WYSIWYG features is quite involved, since it requires a parser and interpreter that "understands" the TikZ code so that it can be rendered and edited in a WYSIWYG manner. We recently wrote such an editor, TikzEdt. This article describes the main programming challenges we faced, and design decisions we made to overcome them. Furthermore, there are some components of our program that can be reused for similar applications.

Another option could be [FlowframTk](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/index.html) (formerly called jpgfdraw).

Comment: This is now available for Linux.

Comment: I stopped using Tikzedt, as the non-functioning cut and paste command when running under linux after a while nearly made me throw my laptop out the window.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton, how did you make it work in Linux? I uncompress the Linux version and I find a bunch of Windows executables that don't even work with `wine` or `mono`.

Comment: in the folder containing the source files, is there a tikzedt file with executable permissions? I simply run that file, it has a single line inside as thus: `mono TikzEdtWForms.exe`.

Comment: Where was that quoted from? https://www.codeproject.com/articles/154371/a-wpf-tikz-editor-tikzedt ?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton I think it's fixed now. (besides, it's open source so everyone can contribute code)

Comment: Unfortunately FlowframTk is not real WYSIWYG (as it cannot import user TikZ code, only export to LaTeX)

Answer (score 11):

I needed a simple graph editor, so finally I rolled my own since I wasn't satisfied with all the solutions. They probably work great for use cases like complicated diagrams, but it took me too long to draw simple graphs (and I needed to draw a lot of them).

You can test the latest version at http://marko.ristin.net/zeichne_tikz and the repository can be found at https://bitbucket.org/markoristin/zeichne_tikz.

Comment: The website no longer works now, (but the repository still works) although the generated code itself looks reasonably clean (but it cannot import code back)

Answer (score 10):

Another tool in this category is **TikZit**.

https://github.com/tikzit/tikzit

> TikZiT is a graphical tool for rapidly creating an editing node-and-edge style graphs. It was originally created to aid in the typesetting of "dot" diagrams of interacting quantum observables (see arXiv:0906.4725), but can be used as a general graph editing program.

Screenshot from the SourceForge project page:

[image]

Comment: Note that TikZiT  is (also) not a real editor (unlike TikZEdt), as it can only understand a subset of TikZ language, but at least it allow the user to edit the code.

Answer (score 9):

The editor you're looking for is TpX.  It doesn't seem to have been worked on in awhile but I use it all the time and it's really great.  It exports a file with it's internal information appearing as `%` comments for TeX with `tikz` code beneath - it will even enclose it in a `figure` environment, so you just include the `.tpx` file and the LaTeX compiler does the rest.

You can find it at:  http://tpx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying version 1.5 (2008-12-07), and the `.tpx` files all have some internal XML representation like `%  <rect x="19.4362" y="46.4017" w="41.3237" h="28.3663"/>`, no `tikz` code anywhere; and if you export, the only thing the `tex` file does is `\put(0,0){\includegraphics{test.pdf}}`, that is includes an already produced PDF. Somehow, I think this tool doesn't export `tikz` code, unfortunately...

Comment: @sdaau - No!  that's not correct.  The author of this code is playing a trick.  He retains the drawing in a special format (the xml you spoke of) that looks commented out and when you set up to "save as" Tikz format, the drawing contains the TpX drawing information (commented out) and Tikz code.  This way, you can simply edit and save the TpX drawing in TpX and simply import this drawing right into your latex - as long as you specified to save in Tikz format.

Answer (score 8):

The [ktikz](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language) / qtikz option mentioned by [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24238/15717) is excellent in my opinion.

Similar functionality on OSX can be obtained with [Fredokun's Tikz Editor](https://github.com/fredokun/TikZ-Editor).

Neither is truly wysiwyg because you still have to write the code, but having a real time preview is a great help in learning the language.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mathcha.io/ is another option (both online or in a desktop version). It does WYSIWYG TikZ, that you can also export to SVG.

Comment: It looks like this one only allow exporting to LaTeX/TikZ instead of import TikZ code? Then in that case it isn't WYSIWYG TikZ (rather it is WYSIWYG of whatever internal format that it uses -- probably a subset of TikZ)

Comment: You’re right, also import is limited to math, not TikZ. So not as fully featured as other editor, but might still be helpful to some people.