# Is There an Online Diagram Graphical Editor that Produces the Corresponding LaTeX Code?

Tags: diagrams, online, mathcha

Is there an online tool that generates the corresponding LaTeX code of a diagram which can be drawn using a graphical interface? A tool such as [`latexdraw`](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/) but only using a web browser (like [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html))?

Comment: @Karlo Thanks for the heads up. Apparently https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz is the new way of doing that.

Comment: github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz seems no longer under active support now.

Comment: Related: [editors - What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 128):

A wonderful option is mathcha: [www.mathcha.io](http://www.mathcha.io)

[image: screenshot of mathcha interface]

just open the editor, you log in
and you make your drawings and equations.

this online program will create different export formats, including Tikz, which is compatible with Latex.

**Edit:**

I see that some people cannot find the menu to export, simply by clicking on the drawing grid, you should notice that a menu appears at the top, you can see the option that says "Tikz", if you click on the triangle on the right side of that button, the option "Copy tikz to clipboard" appears, which is very handy, or even better, you can memorize the keyboard shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + j.

[image: mathcha options]

I want to take the opportunity to comment on another very important function, and it is the one that I point out in the image, called "options" there you can activate or deactivate the "Snap to grid" option, that allows you to align much better the lines or other objects that are being inserted in the drawing, this is very useful. Another interesting feature is to draw with the mouse to look for a latex character that you don't remember or don't know, after clicking on the grid and selecting "*fx*" in the tools on the right side, press the back slash key "\" and the following appears, at the bottom is the "Drawing" option:

[image: options mathcha]

Comment: Where is the PDF export function? I couldn't locate it anywhere. Besides, I can't export the TikZ code (it exports nothing except some opening and closing tags).

Comment: It was a nasty surprise, after spending quite some time creating a drawing, that most of the code exported consisted of remarks saying such code cannot be exported.

Comment: Thanks for this, a nice gem

Comment: Looks like this website does not provide tikz creator anymore. Can someone please confirm

Comment: Sorry my bad. You just have to select the drawing area and then it is all good!

Comment: @Charith the website still generate tikz code

Answer (score 32):

The [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) [online tool](http://www.geogebra.org/webstart/geogebra.html), which can also be installed and run locally, comes to mind. It let's you do geometric drawings: define points, intersections, ellipses given the two foci and a point, etc... It will generate `TikZ` code for you.

For example, create an ellipse within your browser
[image: geogebra online]

This can be exported to `TikZ` (will generate a standalone document), which renders to
[image: geogebra tikz]

Comment: Note that `tikz` code exported by GeoGebra is not of highest quality...

Comment: GeoGebra doesn't make any sense. I tried using it and it keeps producing lines even if when I choose circle.

Comment: The downside seems to be the standalone export. I don't see any option to directly embed the generated TikZ into my own document.

Comment: @MakanTayebi You can easily integrate the file into your own document, see i.e. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beUSEBoci5c).

Answer (score 20):

If you're looking for a tool to draw commutative diagrams with `tikzcd`, there's [Yichuan Shen's tikzcd-editor](http://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/).

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility is to use this online tool called [FreeTikZ](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cheunen/freetikz/) based on `freetikz.sty`. Here the whole code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/01/01]
\ProvidesPackage{freetikz}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,edgelayer,nodelayer,main,foreground,background}

\def\thickness{0.7pt}

\tikzstyle{dot}=[circle, draw=black, fill=black!25, inner sep=.4ex, line width=\thickness, node on layer=foreground]
\tikzstyle{blackdot}=[dot, fill=black!50]
\tikzstyle{blackdot}=[dot, fill=gray!40!white]
\tikzstyle{whitedot}=[dot, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{reddot}=[dot, fill=red]
\tikzstyle{greendot}=[dot, fill=green]

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/on layer/.code={
    \pgfonlayer{#1}\begingroup
    \aftergroup\endpgfonlayer
    \aftergroup\endgroup
  },
  /tikz/node on layer/.code={
    \gdef\node@@on@layer{%
      \setbox\tikz@tempbox=\hbox\bgroup\pgfonlayer{#1}\unhbox\tikz@tempbox\endpgfonlayer\egroup}
    \aftergroup\node@on@layer
  },
  /tikz/end node on layer/.code={
    \endpgfonlayer\endgroup\endgroup
  }
}
\def\node@on@layer{\aftergroup\node@@on@layer}
\makeatother

% Lengths
\newlength\morphismheight
\setlength\morphismheight{0.6cm}
\newlength\minimummorphismwidth
\setlength\minimummorphismwidth{0.6cm}
\newlength\stateheight
\setlength\stateheight{0.6cm}
\newlength\minimumstatewidth
\setlength\minimumstatewidth{0.89cm}
\newlength\connectheight
\setlength\connectheight{0.5cm}
\tikzset{width/.initial=\minimummorphismwidth}

% Keys
\newif\ifwedge\pgfkeys{/tikz/wedge/.is if=wedge}
\tikzset{wedge}
\newif\ifvflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/vflip/.is if=vflip}
\newif\ifhflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/hflip/.is if=hflip}
\newif\ifhvflip\pgfkeys{/tikz/hvflip/.is if=hvflip}
\newif\ifconnectnw\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw/.is if=connectnw}
\newif\ifconnectne\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne/.is if=connectne}
\newif\ifconnectsw\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw/.is if=connectsw}
\newif\ifconnectse\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se/.is if=connectse}
\newif\ifconnectn\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n/.is if=connectn}
\newif\ifconnects\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s/.is if=connects}
\newif\ifconnectnwf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw >/.is if=connectnwf}
\newif\ifconnectnef\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne >/.is if=connectnef}
\newif\ifconnectswf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw >/.is if=connectswf}
\newif\ifconnectsef\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se >/.is if=connectsef}
\newif\ifconnectnf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n >/.is if=connectnf}
\newif\ifconnectsf\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s >/.is if=connectsf}
\newif\ifconnectnwr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect nw </.is if=connectnwr}
\newif\ifconnectner\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect ne </.is if=connectner}
\newif\ifconnectswr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect sw </.is if=connectswr}
\newif\ifconnectser\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect se </.is if=connectser}
\newif\ifconnectnr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect n </.is if=connectnr}
\newif\ifconnectsr\pgfkeys{/tikz/connect s </.is if=connectsr}
\tikzset{keylengthnw/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthn/.initial =\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthne/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthsw/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengths/.initial =\connectheight}
\tikzset{keylengthse/.initial=\connectheight}
\tikzset{connect nw length/.style={connect nw=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n length/.style ={connect n =true, keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne length/.style={connect ne=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw length/.style={connect sw=true, keylengthsw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s length/.style ={connect s =true, keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se length/.style={connect se=true, keylengthse={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect nw < length/.style={connect nw <=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n < length/.style ={connect n <=true,  keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne < length/.style={connect ne <=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw < length/.style={connect sw <=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s < length/.style ={connect s <=true,  keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se < length/.style={connect se <=true, keylengthse={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect nw > length/.style={connect nw >=true, keylengthnw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect n > length/.style ={connect n >=true,  keylengthn ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect ne > length/.style={connect ne >=true, keylengthne={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect sw > length/.style={connect sw >=true, keylengthsw={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect s > length/.style ={connect s >=true,  keylengths ={#1}}}
\tikzset{connect se > length/.style={connect se >=true, keylengthse={#1}}}

% Shapes
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{morphism}
{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
    \anchorborder{\centerpoint}
    \saveddimen\savedlengthnw
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthnw}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthn
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthn}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthne
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthne}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthsw
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthsw}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengths
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengths}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\savedlengthse
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/keylengthse}{\len}
        \pgf@x=\len
    }
    \saveddimen\overallwidth
    {
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/width}{\minwidth}
        \pgf@x=\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \ifdim\pgf@x<\minwidth
            \pgf@x=\minwidth
        \fi
    }
    \savedanchor{\upperrightcorner}
    {
        \pgf@y=.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance\pgf@y by -.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \pgf@x=.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{north}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{north east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \divide \pgf@x by 2
        \advance \pgf@x by 5pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \divide \pgf@x by 2
        \advance \pgf@x by -5pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{north west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{connect nw}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthnw
    }
    \anchor{connect ne}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthne
    }
    \anchor{connect sw}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengthsw
    }
    \anchor{connect se}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengthse
    }
    \anchor{connect n}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by \savedlengthn
    }
    \anchor{connect s}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
        \advance\pgf@y by -\savedlengths
    }
    \anchor{south east}
    {
        \pgf@x=\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{south west}
    {
        \pgf@x=-\overallwidth
        \multiply \pgf@x by 2
        \divide \pgf@x by 5
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{south}
    {
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-0.5\morphismheight
    }
    \anchor{text}
    {
        \upperrightcorner
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \backgroundpath
    {
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\thickness}
        \begin{scope}
                \ifhflip
                    \pgftransformyscale{-1}
                \fi
                \ifvflip
                    \pgftransformxscale{-1}
                \fi
                \ifhvflip
                    \pgftransformxscale{-1}
                    \pgftransformyscale{-1}
                \fi
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                    {-0.5*\overallwidth-5pt}
                    {0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                    {0.5*\overallwidth+5pt}
                    {0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \ifwedge
                    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                        {0.5*\overallwidth + 15pt}
                        {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \else
                    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                        {0.5*\overallwidth + 5pt}
                        {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \fi
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                    {-0.5*\overallwidth-5pt}
                    {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
                \pgfpathclose
                \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \end{scope}
        \ifconnectnw
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectne
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectsw
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {-0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectse
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0.4*\overallwidth}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectn
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnects
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {0pt}
                {-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths}}
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \fi
        \ifconnectnwf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw);
        \fi
        \ifconnectnef
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne);
        \fi
        \ifconnectswf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
        \ifconnectsef
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
        \ifconnectnf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (0,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn);
        \fi
        \ifconnectsf
            \draw [forward arrow style] (0,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths)
                to (0,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
        \ifconnectnwr
            \draw [reverse arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthnw);
        \fi
        \ifconnectner
            \draw [reverse arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthne);
        \fi
        \ifconnectswr
            \draw [reverse arrow style] (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthsw)
                to (-0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
        \ifconnectser
            \draw [reverse arrow style] (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengthse)
                to (0.4*\overallwidth,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
        \ifconnectnr
            \draw [reverse arrow style] (0,0.5*\morphismheight)
                to (0,0.5*\morphismheight+\savedlengthn);
        \fi
        \ifconnectsr
            \draw [reverse arrow style] (0,-0.5*\morphismheight-\savedlengths)
                to (0,-0.5*\morphismheight);
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
```

This is the link to run it:

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cheunen/freetikz/freetikz.html

Replacing the package with `tikz`, however, it is possible to observe that the result is not optimal or exact like the figure below.

[image]

In fact, we have:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (2, 6) to[out=90, in=135] (5, 6);
  \draw (2, 6.5) to[out=0, in=180] (5.5, 6.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For further explanations or informations there is also a link to help the users to use this tool: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2018/01/freetikz.html

Answer (score 11):

TikzEdt is a combined WYSIWYG/text editor designed for editing Tikz code. http://www.tikzedt.org/

Comment: It is a nice tool, but it definitely misses the "Online" part OP asked for.

Comment: Is there an advantage over the WYSIWYG/text editor [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)?

Comment: Either TikzEdt or the requisite mono framework does not work on 64-bit macOS.

Answer (score 3):

I add one link https://pickedshares.com/en/tikz-online-editor/ named **Tikz online editor**. Obviously you need to know the language of `TikZ`.