# How can I draw quickly using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-graphdrawing

I've already asked about how can I draw a similar figure as this one using `Tikz`I just learned the basics of this fascinating library, but I really want to draw complex figures using simple codes :

[image]

Drawing this figure (I didn't achieved it yet) took me one hour !
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[smooth, dashed] (7,-2.15)--(6.5,-2.15);
   \draw[smooth] (7.5,-3) arc (0:90:0.989);
\draw[smooth ,dashed] (6.5,-2)--(6.5,-3)--(7.5,-3) node[right] {$D$};
\draw[smooth] (6.5,-3)--(7,-2.15)node[below, midway] {$r$} node[above]{$M$};
\coordinate(x) at (7,-2.15);
\coordinate(y) at (6.5,-3);
\coordinate(z) at (6.5,-2);
\pic [draw=black!15!black,text=black,angle radius=5mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.3]{angle = x--y--z};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can anyone show me where to find a good book or youtube channel so I can learn more, and yeah I'd be thankful if someone achieved my work. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome! The asnwer, I fear, is that the only solution is practice --- when you'll have drawn 100 figures like the one you show here, you'll need 5 minutes. There are online tools to draw TikZ diagrams without coding, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421731/38080, but if you want to reuse the diagrams and use higher level options I recommend just practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution in plain Ti*k*Z. Your work is already in the right path, you would learn fast from what is posted here. I strongly encourage you to look at the `tkz-euclide` package if you want to draw more easily this kind of graphics.

**EDIT:** I edited the code to let you scale your figure by choosing the value of `\r`and allow the rest of the distances to be automatically calculated (not including the line width).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{4}   % radius
        \def\t{25}  % Theta
        \def\d{2*\r/5}  % distance for Theta angle mark
        
        \draw (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (\r,0) coordinate (D) arc (0:90:\r) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,0) -- (90-\t:\r) coordinate (M) node [midway,right] {$r$};
        \draw (0,\d) arc (90:90-\t:\d) node [midway,above] {$\theta$};
        
        \node [below left] at (O) {$O$};
        \node [below right] at (D) {$D$};
        \node [above left] at (C) {$C$};
        \node [above left=3pt and -5pt] at (M) {$M$};
        
        % Vectors
        \begin{scope}[line width=1.5pt,-stealth]
            \draw[red] (M) --++ (0,-3*\r/5) node [midway,right] {$\vec{P}$};
            \draw[olive] (M) -- ($(M)+(-\t:\r/2)$) node [midway,above] {$\vec{u}$};
            \draw[olive] (M) -- ($(M)!0.4!(O)$) node [midway,left] {$\vec{n}$};
            
            \draw[blue] (M) -- ($(M)!-0.5!(O)$) node [midway,left] {$\vec{R}$};
            
        \end{scope}
        \def\angledist{0.05*\r} % distance for right angle
        \draw[olive,line width=1pt] (M)--++ (-90-\t:\angledist) --++ (-\t:\angledist) --++ (90-\t:\angledist);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Vectors]

Comment: I just edited my post to change a bit into the code, just to let you adjust the radius and not be obliged to manually adjust other lengths. Now everything (except line width) is automatic.