# Sequence of upgrading to TeX Live 2013

Tags: installing, texlive, emacs, windows

Since TUG says there is no upgrade from TeX Live 2012 to 2013, it has to be a new install. However, I do not want to have two versions of TeX Live and I don't want to mess up system `PATH` (Windows 7). Is it the right procedure to uninstall 2012 first, and then install 2013 ? Will other programs such as Emacs redirect link to new 2013 installation correctly?

---

### Update

I ended up install 2013 first, changed system environment PATH and made sure things work, and then uninstalled 2012. So I guess the order doesn't matter as long as the PATH is correct.

Comment: Well, this is what I do. I am on windows also. I downloaded VBox. Also downloaded Linux mint 15 ISO image, booted it. Now downloaded TL 2013, installed in the new VM Linux machine, then mounted my C: drive as shared folder. Bring up terminal window in VM, typed latex. Used Windows file manager to look at the resulting pdf. I am still on windows, but using TL 2013 on Linux. When I want to upgrade to TL 2014, I make new VM and delete the old one. If I mess up the installation, then delete the VM and make new one.

Comment: @Nasser That's quite an extreme solution :)

Comment: @Xavier actually, this is how I do all my work on my PC, for years now. Linux is just another window on the desktop. One can think of it as a DOS window if they want, but it is just another window really. Can copy/paste from it to windows apps, etc.. All my data is on NTFS, but Linux does not care where it is, it just sees it as /shared_point/data. It is the best of both worlds way to do work. Use the best tool from each OS. I use Linux for all the useful tools (Latex, Make, bash, etc...) and use windows for browsing the net and using VISIO program (this is until I learn Tikz :)

Comment: @Nasser People on Linux also browse the net :) More seriously, there are a couple of Visio replacement programs that can directly export to tikz/pgf, such as [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) (works on Linux and Windows). More here: [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235/10102)

Comment: I don't know if I set it up myself, but I have an environment variable called $TEXBIN that, well, points to my TeX bin folder. This allows me to have multiple simultaneous installations, switching whenever I want.  Emacs just knows the variable path.

Comment: I would also like to know how to migrate the list of installed packages. I am too lazy to buy a new harddrive, and mine is full, so installing a full TL appears to be impossible for me.

Comment: @SeanAllred, I couldn't find the `$TEXBIN` environment variable on my computer, but I have `C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32` in my `PATH` variable.

Comment: Q1.Is it the right procedure to `uninstall 2012 first`, and then `install 2013`? **Answer: Yes** Q2. Will other programs such as Emacs redirect link to new 2013 installation correctly ? **Answer: Yes** if you use [install-tl.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip) from http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can uninstall 2012 and then install 2013 first.

As long as you change the path variable, Emacs will find it.  The path variable can be found by:

```
 1. right clicking my computer

 2. going to properties

 3. then advanced system settings

 4. and in the systems properties window go to environmental variables
```

Once there, you will see a systems variables box with a scroll bar and this is where you can set and change path variables in Windows.

I don't use Windows so I have not idea what you would change the variable too but that is where you will find it.  Also, I am not sure what it will be called but it should be obviously related to TeXLive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a batch file to update the path. Write the following code in a plain text file, name it `updatepath.bat` (for example).

```
rem name it as updatepath.bat for example
rem it must be invoked with administrative privilege!
rem the following is just for an example
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader
PATH=%PATH%;C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32

setx PATH "%PATH%" /m
```

Whenever you want to update the path (after installing TeX Live and other programs listed above),  you can just run the batch file by right clicking the icon and select "Run as administrator".

Note: The batch file has not implemented path duplication, so make sure that you update the path just once even though duplication is not harmful.