# Package for more creative text formatting in latex

Tags: formatting, packages

What is a reasonable package to be used for realizing something like the following example (including image altered):

[image: Included image altered]

The source is http://blog.azubiyo.de/bewerbungstipps/deckblatt-bewerbung/attachment/deckblatt-muster-4/ (a PDF file can be downloaded from there) and this belongs to a blog entry in German AZUBIYO-Blog: [Deckblatt in der Bewerbung? Vorlagen und Muster](http://blog.azubiyo.de/bewerbungstipps/deckblatt-bewerbung/), where the following copy rights are given:

> Bildnachweise: © lev dolgachov-fotolia, © Minerva Studio-fotolia; Urheber Design 1 & 2: Designbewerbung

Comment: You're going to want to look into TikZ.  As it stands unfortunately, this question airs more on the side of 'do it for me' instead of 'how can I solve this specific problem.

Comment: Maybe look at `flowfram`, too. Note that questions which just post an image and ask for a solution are not really reasonable for this site, though you may be lucky if somebody is sufficiently intrigued. To increase the chances of receiving useful advice, please post a Minimal (non-)Working Example which at least shows what you have tried or gives the basics of the content you want included. That makes it a lot easier for people to help and demonstrates that you have made some effort to solve the problem yourself. Also, please read the question back and edit accordingly (different what?).

Comment: Okay, I changed the question... I am asking for the package, not the concrete example to be realized. Sorry, for being vague. I can't see how TikZ will help skimming the first 100 pages of its manual, but flowfram seems to be a good solution.

Comment: `\usepackage{inDesign}` ;)

Comment: Pleasedon't reveal personal information without the consent of the actualowner of that info.

Comment: Thx, but Mustermann is german for "anyone" http://www.dict.cc/?s=Max+Mustermann

Comment: @percusse The name "Mustermann" and the address "Musterweg" is something like the english "John Doe".

Comment: @HenriMenke I know that, it's a generic comment but the picture is a 3D render?

Comment: Let me add a generic text building block. I have to do this separately after this one, because it is quite long. You are lucky, that you found one of the mentioned “procrastination team”. ;-)

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: @percusse I googled and found, that the image is from a template available here: http://blog.azubiyo.de/bewerbungstipps/deckblatt-bewerbung/attachment/deckblatt-muster-4/

Comment: @MarcPalm: Before you next time post an image, check the copy right!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Procrastination team, represent!

---

This is just too easy with TikZ `;-)`

Now with correct colors, correct font and the code matches the picture. You will need to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` to typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,mwe}
\definecolor{cvgreen}{HTML}{92D14F}
\definecolor{cvgray}{HTML}{D8E4BE}
\definecolor{cvtext}{HTML}{92909B}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % green bar
    \fill[cvgreen] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=5cm]current page.south west);
    % gray bar
    \fill[cvgray] ([yshift=-5cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-10cm]current page.north east);
    % title and date
    \node[cvtext,right] at ([yshift=-7cm]current page.north west) {\addfontfeature{Scale = 5}\bfseries Bewerbung als Bankkauffrau};
    \node[cvtext,above left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-9.5cm]current page.north east) {\huge\bfseries zum 01.09.2013};
    % cover photo
    \node[inner sep=0pt,below right] (image) at ([xshift=5cm,yshift=-10cm]current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=9cm]{example-image-a}};
    % name and address
    \node[fill=white,drop shadow,align=center,text width=6.4cm,inner sep=0.3cm,below] (name) at (image.south) {\LARGE Martina Mustermann};
    \node[text width=15cm,inner sep=0.3cm,below right] at (name.south west) {\Large\obeylines%
        Musterweg 8
        81929 München
        Tel.: 01 74 / 98 98 61
        E-Mail: Martina.M@web.de
    };
    % attachments
    \node[white,text width=5cm,inner sep=0.3cm,above right] at ([yshift=1cm]current page.south west) {\large\obeylines%
        \textbf{Anlagen:}
        Lebenslauf
        Bewerbungsschreiben
        Letzte 2 Schulzeugnisse
        Praktikumsbestätigungen
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: wow! Tikz is just like inDesign now (but better because one can do math with it). very nice. I am going to learn Tikz once someone puts a GUI front end to it :)

Comment: Amazing, thank you for realizing the specific example. I wouldn't have dare to ask for, but I am really impressed.

Comment: Wrong colours. ;-) (In other words, one upvote is mine.)

Comment: Does the `mwe` package provide this Martina pic? I can't see why you included the package. (Or the image doesn't match the code.)

Comment: @Speravir Now with correct colours AND correct font!

Comment: @HenriMenke: Alas, lovely Martina looks now a bit strange …

Comment: @Nasser If you look for a TikZ GUI, you might be interested in [KTikZ/QTikZ](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/). Maybe you also want to have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz

Answer (score 24):

Just for fun:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gdef\shift{0}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{random(0,5)}
    \xdef\shift{\shift,\r}
  }
  \foreach \sh in {0,...,5}{
    \gdef\rec{0}
    \foreach \s [count=\c] in \shift { \ifnum\s=\sh \xdef\rec{\rec,\c} \fi }
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \foreach \x in \rec {(0, \x pt) rectangle ++(110pt,1pt)};
      \node[anchor=south west] at (\sh pt,0)
      {\includegraphics[width=100pt,height=100pt]{example-image-a}};
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```