# pgf-Tikz code generator for Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, code

LatexDraw is a PSTricks code generator for Latex.
LatexDraw generates PSTricks codes of any fugure are drawn.

[image]

Are there any such tools that will generate pgf-tikz code of any figure for latex?
If yes please suggest me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Inkscape can export Tikz code.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz?lq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex

Comment: Try GeoGebra it generates tikz code.

Comment: The current 3.3.1 version of latexdraw needs to be improved further. Otherwise, I would prefer Geogebra even in creating flowchart