# Where can I find the resources to create a preview progam like qtikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

Writing tikz code can take a lot of time especially if there are a lot of figures that I want to code in LaTeX. As such, I think it would be a good side project to write a photoshop-like program to handle tikz diagrams. To do this requires being able to find documentation of how Tikz works.

Comment: There is Inkscape2TikZ already so you can take it from there.

Comment: TikZ/PGF is not a _drawing tool_ ! It is a _programming tool_ to draw.

Comment: Related: [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235/1952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Tikz/PGF manual is very detailed](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf), or you could look at the [source code itself.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/)

Depending on your goals, you might want to use the underlying PGF tools instead of the Tikz tools intended for user legibility, because that would probably be easier to program.

Also please release for mac! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use the analogy Tikz is to PGF what LaTeX is to TeX?

Comment: This goes beyond my knowledge of `PGF/Tikz`, to be honest, it's addressed on page 25 (the introduction) of the manual. Rereading it now I think it may be bad advice—implementing Tikz might give you better support? I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually @user3100403 I'll re-eat my words, the right answer is *yes*, `Tikz` is a layer of macros for `PGF`. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Check out Page 968 of the `Tikz/PGF` manual, I think that will be helpful for how to use this programmatically