# Do I need to hand-code my TikZ pictures or is there an editor I can use?

Tags: tikz-pgf

With that said, I have tried [TikZiT](http://tikzit.sourceforge.net/) which does provide a minimal user interface for dragging elements, and creating edges. But it's quite hard to understand and I haven't for example understood how to even create simple text elements. Is there a more mature version that anybody knows about, or do you guys just hand code it?

Comment: I always "hand code it", as in, I type it out. There are many programs that work with a WYSIWYG interface, but with Tikz, and Latex in general, I always type it. Although it might seem tedious, it's part of why I love Tikz. I like typing stuff and seeing it create stuff. :D Also, not less important, Tikz is a mathematically precise tool. When you calculate coordinates or use a `\foreach`, the result is mathematically precise. At least more than dragging elements, which will not be precise unless there is a snap-to-grid feature which I doubt exists.

Comment: If you're plotting out data, that makes sense. But I'm not plotting out data. I'm simply drawing graphs, boxes, arrows. Perhaps I should look into Inkscape SVG export functionality.

Comment: I was not talking about plots. But yes, that might be a solution. :)

Comment: See [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235) I guess your question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Aren't WYSIWYG text editors different from graphical editors?

Comment: That question isn't about text editors. See also [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972) by the way. (Oh, and to make sure people are notified about your comments, write `@username`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz)

Answer (score 2):

Check out GeoGebra (https://www.geogebra.org/). It has functionality to export to TeX. The code is messy, as much machine generated code usually is, but it is very easy to clean up and takes much of the work out of drawing geometric diagrams.

Comment: Does it export TikZ code?

Comment: @Werner TikZ or PSTricks at least, the last time I looked.

Comment: @Werner And Asymptote (http://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Export_to_LaTeX_(PGF,_PSTricks)_and_Asymptote). Can't find those options in the web interface though, so one likely needs the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `Dia` http://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/.  It can export pgf code which compiles with the tikz package.

This is a drawing editor with lots of templated objects you can use and include in the diagram.  I have had students in the past use this for UML diagrams, flowcharts, etc which they then exported to a file and used `\input{filename}` to get code into the LaTeX file.  Or they just copied and pasted.

I personally have used it for small diagrams to put in exams and is quick and easy.

I just installed it on Win8.1 and made a quick sketch, exported as *.pgf code and successfully compiled with MikTeX2.9 using TeXmaker 4.1.1

Major disadvantages:

**1)** The program builds all diagrams as absolute positioning, NOTHING is done relative.  And the resulting code is in the order that you did the original drawing.

**2)** If you plan to edit the diagram further in `dia` then you must also save it in the native format for `dia`, as you cannot import tikz/pgf code.

**3)** Large and complicated diagrams will be very difficult to edit in any fashion with a LaTeX IDE.