# Creating codes by drawing figures

Tags: plot

I am beginners to LaTeX and I have been trying to learn Ti*k*z & PSTricks for graphics.

My Question is: Is there any other software available in which we can draw our desirable figures (like graphs of equations, all mathematics geometric figures and etc.) and  which help us to generate codes for figure?

Comment: Related: [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235)

Comment: By the way, have you created all/any these users? http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/90088/snehal http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/94159/snehal http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/93052/snehal http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/94104/snehal http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/94203/snehal http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/92835/snehal If so, why don't you create an account (http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) so you have easier access to all your questions? You can have the different accounts merged, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: ok i will signing up for my account actually i thought without creating an account just i post my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tools able to generate tikz code are listed at http://tikz.de/tools
(sorry, the comments on that page are in german, but the links work in any language ...). Tikz, on its own, can be used to create beautiful graphs of equations, like so

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}   
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={very thick}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dashed,gray}}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={white}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=9,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every outer x axis line/.append style={|->},
    every outer y axis line/.append style={|->},
    width=16cm,
    major tick length=1cm,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot[blue,samples=500,domain=-10:260] {-2 * x*x + 500 * x};
    \draw[red!50!black] (axis cs:125,31300) -- (axis cs:125,0);
    \legend{$A(x)=-2x² + 500x$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The right side of the equation `A(x)=-2x² + 500x` is argument to `\addplot[...]{...}`.