# Editor for creating Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm writing a technical report and I would like to include some graphics. Of course I could do them in TikZ but I don't know it and thus it is very time consuming. Another option would be to do it with Inkscape but the disadvantage is that it does not adapt to the LaTeX document (font size etc.).

Is there an editor which allows creating graphics by just drag & drop (like Microsoft Paint) and which produces TikZ output in high quality? The platform used is Windows 10, 64-bit.

Comment: see http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/#tools-that-generate-pgftikz-code

Comment: Inkscape can export TikZ code.

Comment: Are the graphics very complicated? Depending on the nature of the stuff you need to create, I'd suggest trying to create something basic, you can always ask here if you get stuck (check if there are existing questions first). The manual is very thorough for most cases you might encounter, and Tikz is not *that* hard to start with. :D

Comment: See also [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235)|0.8616