# Is there any solid WYSIWYG editor for Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to design a company logo via Tikz and thought an editor would be a huge plus to the task. Are there any good drag and drop (with minimal coding) Tikz editor? Platform is Mac OS X. I am using Sketch but would love to use Tikz.

Comment: Have a look at [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents). For a logo you could use for example Inkscape: "A very powerful and well-supported SVG editor. Can be used to export TikZ code."

Comment: Well... the only tool I know able to generate Tikz code is Inkscape. It's multiplatform and there is a plug-in for Tikz, in my opinion you could draw your logo easily in inkscape and later export it into Tikz.

Comment: Why do you want to use TikZ (an acronym that means : Tikz is NOT a drawing program) instead of Sketch ? The whole point of TikZ is to be a tool for programming graphics.

Comment: @marsupilam because I am in love with TikZ.

Comment: That's a great reason.

Comment: @seteropere Can't argue with that ! `:)`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz