# TikZ overlay over png image

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a png image I would like to overlay. The image is below:
[image: A png image of a powerpoint slide.]

I have the Tikz code which has been generated in TpX:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.00mm, y=1.00mm, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=0pt, outer xsep=0pt, outer ysep=0pt]
\path[line width=0mm] (-32.00,-5.73) rectangle +(175.14,83.73);
\definecolor{L}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (101.00,73.00) ellipse (5.00mm and 3.00mm);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (110.00,73.00) -- (106.50,73.00);
\definecolor{F}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L, fill=F] (106.50,73.00) -- (107.90,72.30) -- (106.50,73.00) -- (107.90,73.70) -- (106.50,73.00) -- cycle;
\definecolor{T}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\draw[T] (110.50,72.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{Page number where}};
\draw[T] (110.50,68.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{content can be found}};
\draw[T] (110.50,64.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{in the textbook}};
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (25.50,20.00) ellipse (8.50mm and 3.00mm);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (0.00,30.00) -- (17.00,21.00);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L, fill=F] (17.00,21.00) -- (16.09,22.27) -- (17.00,21.00) -- (15.44,21.04) -- (17.00,21.00) -- cycle;
\draw[T] (-30.00,30.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{If I indicate a Table}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,26.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{in my slides you}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,22.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{need to know the }};
\draw[T] (-30.00,18.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{contents of the table}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,14.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{or, in this case, know}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,10.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{what the information}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,6.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{means.}};
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (49.50,12.00) ellipse (8.50mm and 3.00mm);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (110.00,32.00) -- (57.50,13.00);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L, fill=F] (57.50,13.00) -- (59.05,12.82) -- (57.50,13.00) -- (58.58,14.13) -- (57.50,13.00) -- cycle;
\draw[T] (110.50,30.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{The figures tell a}};
\draw[T] (110.50,26.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{story. You need to }};
\draw[T] (110.50,22.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{know that story,}};
\draw[T] (110.50,18.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{especially if I take}};
\draw[T] (110.50,14.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{the time to point the}};
\draw[T] (110.50,10.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{figure out to you in}};
\draw[T] (110.50,6.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{my slides.}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
```

The code works fine. I just can't figure out how to place the annotation over the image so it looks like this:[image: Image of slide with correctly overlaid text and arrows.]

I have looked at other examples and tried to replicate them but simply don't know enough about Tikz to do it correctly.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I understand TpX is outdated... if anyone can suggest a newer WYSIWYG interface that will generate Tikz code that I can insert into my tex files that would also be much appreciated. TpX didn't handle png etc... well hence my problem above.

Comment: Take a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the TpX code, you only need to add the image in a `\node` at the start of the `tikzpicture`:

```
\node [anchor=south west] at (0,-3.5) {\includegraphics[width=10.5cm]{diagram}};
```

It takes a bit of trial and error to work out an appropriate coordinate and size of the image.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.00mm, y=1.00mm, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=0pt, outer xsep=0pt, outer ysep=0pt]

% add only this line
\node [anchor=south west] at (0,-3.5) {\includegraphics[width=10.5cm]{diagram}};

\path[line width=0mm] (-32.00,-5.73) rectangle +(175.14,83.73);
\definecolor{L}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (101.00,73.00) ellipse (5.00mm and 3.00mm);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (110.00,73.00) -- (106.50,73.00);
\definecolor{F}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L, fill=F] (106.50,73.00) -- (107.90,72.30) -- (106.50,73.00) -- (107.90,73.70) -- (106.50,73.00) -- cycle;
\definecolor{T}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\draw[T] (110.50,72.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{Page number where}};
\draw[T] (110.50,68.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{content can be found}};
\draw[T] (110.50,64.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{in the textbook}};
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (25.50,20.00) ellipse (8.50mm and 3.00mm);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (0.00,30.00) -- (17.00,21.00);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L, fill=F] (17.00,21.00) -- (16.09,22.27) -- (17.00,21.00) -- (15.44,21.04) -- (17.00,21.00) -- cycle;
\draw[T] (-30.00,30.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{If I indicate a Table}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,26.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{in my slides you}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,22.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{need to know the }};
\draw[T] (-30.00,18.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{contents of the table}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,14.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{or, in this case, know}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,10.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{what the information}};
\draw[T] (-30.00,6.00) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{means.}};
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (49.50,12.00) ellipse (8.50mm and 3.00mm);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L] (110.00,32.00) -- (57.50,13.00);
\path[line width=0.30mm, draw=L, fill=F] (57.50,13.00) -- (59.05,12.82) -- (57.50,13.00) -- (58.58,14.13) -- (57.50,13.00) -- cycle;
\draw[T] (110.50,30.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{The figures tell a}};
\draw[T] (110.50,26.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{story. You need to }};
\draw[T] (110.50,22.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{know that story,}};
\draw[T] (110.50,18.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{especially if I take}};
\draw[T] (110.50,14.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{the time to point the}};
\draw[T] (110.50,10.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{figure out to you in}};
\draw[T] (110.50,6.50) node[anchor=base west]{\fontsize{11.38}{13.66}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{my slides.}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Torbjørn, I was very close! Now I see the mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Ignasi,

While none of the WYSIWYG provided a solution (none allow me to build a Tikz drawing around a png and then export the code centered around an includable png) I did learn enough to solve my own problem, building the picture from scratch:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=8.5cm]{image.png}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
%        \draw[help lines,xstep=.05,ystep=.05] (0,0) grid (1,1);
%        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
%        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \path[color=black,draw=red,miter limit=4.00,nonzero rule,line width=1pt]    (0.965,0.975) ellipse (0.5cm and 0.25cm);
    \draw[color=red,line width=1pt] (1.021,0.975) -- (1.07,0.975);
    \node[text width=3cm,text=blue] at (1.25,0.975) {Some text.};
    \path[color=black,draw=red,miter limit=4.00,nonzero rule,line width=1pt]    (0.47,0.198) ellipse (0.8cm and 0.27cm);
    \draw[color=red,line width=1pt] (0.565,0.198) -- (1.07,0.25);
    \node[text width=3cm,text=blue] at (1.25,0.2) {Some more text.};
        \path[color=black,draw=red,miter limit=4.00,nonzero rule,line width=1pt]    (0.24,0.3) ellipse (0.8cm and 0.2cm);
        \draw[color=red,line width=1pt] (0.145,0.3) -- (-0.02,0.3);
    \node[text width=3cm,text=blue] at (-.2,0.3) {Still some more text.};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would still like to know how to do this using the code produced by TpX as that is such an easy program to use for what I need to do.