# Looking for software like JaxoDraw for general graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I just got to know the [JaxoDraw](http://jaxodraw.sourceforge.net/index.html) software, which is a Java program for drawing Feynman diagrams. The cool thing about this program is the possibility of generating LaTeX code. Is there a similar program for graphics in general?

Comment: Related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex?noredirect=1&lq=1