# Looking for a web site or a tool to edit TeX and get instant preview in parallel

Tags: compiling, editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex)

There are some online TeX editors which allow to type TeX source, compile it and see the output. I am looking for something different, I am wondering if there exists some sites which let type TeX source and see the output at the same time. It is quite similar to the editor of StackExchange: when we type a post, we see the instant preview below... Stack Exchange Mathematics also allows to edit mathematical formula under TeX format, and see the preview below...

If there is no suitable web site, is there a software under Ubuntu to do so? It seems that there are some tools which compile after each save, that is not what I am looking for...

Could anyone give any suggestion? Thank you very much

Comment: For the non-online part of your question see [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex). For TikZ diagrams see also [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz).

Comment: I don't know of any online Tex editors that give you that immediate compilation. With respect to software, I love [Gummi](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/) which is free under Ubuntu. Gummi is XeLaTeX or PDFLatex but I feel performance drops for big documents. If you don't mind paying for software, look into [BakomaTex](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/)

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28952/pdf-reader-on-linux-capable-of-continuous-updating/28956#28956) provides a solution incorporating automated save and compile using `vim` on Linux.