# make flashmode work

Tags: macros, installing, compiling, mac, preview

I am not sure whether this is an appropriate question for tex.SE. Anyway: I am trying to use Flashmode, which I discovered reading the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex).

Unfortunately I am not able to make it work. The best that I am able to get is the following: the .tex file is saved immediately after any modification (as expected), but the preview does *not* change. Did anyone of you experience the same problem? Do you know how to solve it?

I think I did all I was supposed to do (I followed in particular the [original site](http://web.me.com/gerhardt/Flashmode/) and [this other site](http://tekonomist.wordpress.com/tag/flashmode/).
Maybe it's just a little detail that I'm missing...

Comment: The preview won't change if there are any errors in the compilation.  Are you sure that's the case?

Comment: @AlanMunn yes, because the "manual" compilation works fine.

Comment: I don't think we can hope to answer this as it stands: for too vague. 'Not a Real Question'.