# Software which compiles scripts automatically

Tags: compiling

I'm using MikTex. However, it's quite annoying to me that I have to compile the scripts manually. Is there any software which compiles the scripts automatically. By this I mean the automatic compilation on Stack Exchange.

Comment: BaKoMa TeX does on-the-fly compilation. Or you could use LyX.  Otherwise, no, there are no means of automatic compiling.  Maybe I've misunderstood your question. Are you talking about compiling sample documents here on the site? Or automatically compiling your own documents as you write them?

Comment: Thanks!!! Just 2 more questions: what are the limitations of these 2, comparing to other manually-compiled softwares? Which one would you suggest or prefer?

Comment: I mean, automatically compiling at the time I write them. Exactly like when you type your question or answer on Stack Exchange.

Comment: BaKoMa TeX is not free but is otherwise good, from what I understand. I  don't know how up-to-date it is with respect to packages.  LyX is not directly LaTeX but uses LaTeX behind the scenes and can export LaTeX documents. Most of us here don't use either of them, but instead just compile manually when we need to. See [Real Time LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75844/2693). Your question is a duplicate of this.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot !!!