# TikZ editor for Mac OS

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac, tools

I'm looking for an editor like [tikzedt](http://www.tikzedt.org/index.html) for Mac OS X. Or something similar in order to write and see quickly the result.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: This looks like a neat tool. As far as I know there is no equivalent for the Mac. The developers have released a Linux version of their code, so I assume it could also be built to run on a Mac.  You might want to ask them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz)

Comment: @m0nhawk A TikZ editor might be useful even without WYSIWYG, help in writing, syntax checks, ...

Comment: A possible solution is to use the best Software ever made for vector graphics on Mac: Adobe Illustrator. Once you have your picture in EPS format, you can convert it to TIKZ with eps2pgf.
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/eps2pgf/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all I'd like to suggest you to take a look at this page: [TikZ Resources](http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/). There is a list of tools that you can use to work with TikZ. It is must-have bookmark, full of resources, articles and examples.

I would suggest you to use this tool: [TikZiT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tikzit/).

Comment: Note however that this requires building it from the source.  *Really not* a big deal, but a little off-putting for many users.

Comment: Actually you can download the binaries, at least for Mac OSX.

Comment: Ah yes I see -- for 0.8.  0.9 only has a DOS-executable.

Comment: TikZiT looked promising, but the version 0.8 didn't actually seem to work under OX X 10.9 (it could draw points, but didn't parse or produce tikz code).

Comment: I could not even get version 1.0 to compile in Xcode 5.1. The code is written using garbage collection which is not available anymore. Does anyone have a working binary for 1.0 and Mac OS X?

Answer (score 15):

I think [TikZ-Editor](https://github.com/fredokun/TikZ-Editor) is what you are searching for. It has a beautiful Mac-ish interface and the same features as tikzedt.

And just to complete the list – I used [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) before, it also provides live preview and an even better interface. You can use Latexian for editing full LaTeX-Files, too.

Edit: As I just saw, there is no WYSIWYG-Editing in TikZ-Editor...

Answer (score 10):

(I know an answer has already been accepted, but I can't pass over this editor)

Another very good editor is [Latexit](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en&PHPSESSID=ea686bd2aaf16faab0d8767e56ed4d49). Its main purpose is to write equations that can then be sent to other applications, but it has many other uses. I use it to draw my tikz pictures. It is easy to use. In addition it has a library, where you can store all of your art and reuse it later. Once your picture is complete you can paste the code into your TeX document, or save it in many different formats.

Comment: This is a very good way to do it with a light tool. It is a solution that I'll try to consider more deeply.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a non-answer, but now a year after the original question was posed, I think it is important to make a comment. I've tried [TikZiT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tikzit/) and [TiKZ-Editor](https://github.com/fredokun/TikZ-Editor), but unfortunately, both these programs are still very limited. I gave up and ran Parallels Desktop and [TikZEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/) and have to say that this Windows version is far superior than the alternatives on OSX.

It is a pain to run a virtual desktop, but I think in this case it is worth it, assuming you have access to Windows and Parallels.

Answer (score 2):

Sourceforge is misbehaving at the moment, so I can't post a new release of TikZit. In the mean time, here is the version I use:

http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/aleks.kissinger/resource/TikZiT.zip

It works on Mavericks, but I haven't tested on Yosemite. The latest version in the repo doesn't build on Mavericks however, because of this ARC issue some people have already pointed out. Hopefully we'll have that sorted out soon.