# What is the optimal LaTeX WYSIWYG editor/platform (quality/price) for Windows 8?

Tags: math-mode, editors, windows, wysiwyg

I am doing lots of Math and also writing; want to use in the future LaTeX and seeking the adivce of this community.
What is the optimal WYSIWYG editor/platform (quality/price) for Windows 8? Why?

Comment: Related (not a dupe) is [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339). A couple of things here. Most LaTeX users go for code/preview rather than 'WYSIWYG-like' interfaces, and indeed options are limited in that area. Secondly, I wonder if you could add some specifics on your requirements, as otherwise this could be considered 'primarily opinion based'.

Comment: I am seeking for a real (instantaneous) wyswyg that helps particularly with fast math editing options. Also the whole project environment being enabled and facilitated well. I have the impression that there are some shareware that probably better in relation price/quality than the commercial one. But except trying all I can not make a judgment where to go.

Comment: I just found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors It seems indeed there does not exist any for Windows 8 or is there any other suggestion?

Comment: The Wikipedia list covers all editors, which are mainly code-based (see my other comment). I'm not surprised there is no explicit mention of Windows 8: broadly programs for Win7 or earlier are likely to run, and with most users not adopting Windows 8 at present its not a priority for developers.

Comment: Is there any good editor (even not WYSWYG) that one could be *sure* that works for W8 without bad surprises?

Comment: Maybe WxMaxima also worth trying. It is not exactly what you want . but you can do a lot of symbolic/numerical calculations and then export the equations in LaTeX format. consider it an opensource version of Mathematica.

Comment: See also: [compiling - Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As far I know, one nice true WYSIWYG editor that is [BaKoMa](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/), although include also a source editor. There are licenses since 55$ but there are a evaluation period, so you can test for free if the ratio quality/price is enough.

Another shareware program,[Scientific Workplace](http://www.mackichan.com/) is a WYSIWYW  (what you see is what you want, nearly to a WYSIWYG) that import/export to LaTeX and other formats and include built-in computer algebra system.  I have not tested this software.

A free option could be GNU [TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) that is a free WYSIWYW but is not a true TeX editor, since files are saved in TeXmacs formats, but include converters for TeX/LaTeX and other formats.

Similarly, [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) is a free  WYSIWYM (what you see is what you mean) where the source text is formated according to the structure of the document (for example, the name of sections is showed with the final numeration and with a bold a larger font) but in far of a true preview because things as margins or number of pages are showed only in the preview of the PDF). The philosophy of a WYSIWYM is that you are not distracted from the contents by the LateX commands nor the final format.  Again, this is not really a true LaTeX editor, but convert **perfectly** to LaTeX. This is often the option preferred by many LaTeX novices (and several experts too).

Disclaimer: The above programs have all Windows versions, but I am not tested any of these programs in any version of Windows.

Personally, among the above I prefer LyX, but more than LyX a true source editor as TeXworks (included with TeX Live) that showed easily a preview that can be synchronized with the source (clicking on the PDF go to the corresponding source, and *vice versa*). Please see the comparison of LaTeX editors in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Excellent response. Meanwhile installed and use Texmaker (TeXworks pendant). Can confirm that Texmaker works fine under Windows 8. Some minor issue like better running in Admin Mode and run compatibility check via right mouse click on program. Then necessary to cross over the bug with the PDF converter, press just F6 and the bug removes. It works all well with MiKTeX latest in background. Hope that helps everybody.

Comment: Instead of texmaker, you could try TeXnicCenter : http://www.texniccenter.org/
Very stable, productive, but not WYSIWYG (would you care while writing a whole book ?).

Comment: One comment about Scientific Workplace.  I was helping a colleague who had it, and his version could not handle e-tex.  Further, I found nothing on the web to make me think that deficiency had been resolved in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

You also can use WinEdt 8 (shareware), almost entirely customisable via a powerful system of macros (over 1,000!) and a very reactive community.

Just two examples of what can be done to ease typing: a shortcut to type set greek letters in formulae is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd> to obtain `\beta`. This is in the the standard configuration, but one can do more: it typesets `β` but saves it as `\beta`. When you re-open the file, `\beta` is again converted to `β`. This is for the legibility of the source code.

Second example: there is a system of personal abbreviations, so that your usual mistyping (everyone has…) is automatically corrected or usual phrases are completed (e.g. `sln` -> `solution`).

Comment: I will use the editor, looks like it has more features than plan notepad.

Answer (score 4):

I use Scientific Workplace (SWP), Version 5.5. I have used SWP since the mid-1990's and have been pleased with it. I have written several books with it, many research papers, and many exams. Their Beamer template is also good for presentation slides.

At present, I am using SWP under both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. It works fine!

Kendall Atkinson

Comment: I left a comment to Fran's answer that my exposure to Scientific Workplace showed it not able to handle e-tex.  Does your version, for example, allow you to load and use the `etoolbox` package?

Comment: I have used SWP, and have co-authors who do. The inferface is great, but overall it is a dreadful program, I would not recommend anybody using it. Three main problems a) at times it will crash and when doing so delete part of the file you are working on; b) it rewrites the LaTeX files it is working on, in particular expanding the \newcommand's; c) there are lots of standard packages which are at least partially incompatible with SW.

Answer (score 4):

My vote goes for LyX.

1. It’s free
2. You can edit **both** WYSIWYG part and LaTeX code

   - WARNING1: works flawlessly only in math mode
   - WARNING2: therefore, each time just copy-paste your math TeX source into “normal” latex editor

Crash course: math in LyX

- open LyX -> new document -> view -> toolbars -> check math (auto)
- view -> toolbars -> check source pane
- push button at the bottom left of the screen (Set display mode)

Start you equation in WYSIWYG, if you need to insert code, press CTRL+L or simply backslash

Answer (score 3):

I like [Infty Editor](http://www.inftyproject.org/en/software.html#InftyEditor). It's freemium. It only runs on Windows though.

Comment: I haven't heard of this editor. Can you please expand your answer to tell us more about InftyEditor, and also add a review to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/24113)?