# Instant preview for Asymptote?

Tags: compiling, asymptote

[KtikZ/QtikZ](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) is handy for previewing TikZ code.

Is there an equivalent for Asymptote?

Comment: I haven't used it, but have you tried Asymptote's interactive drawing mode? http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Tutorial.html

Comment: @mrc, yes, the problem is that drawings in interactive mode are definitive, we can't erase mistakes, at least I don't know how. I'm very new to Asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

`xasy` provides a rudimentary but usable graphical interface for Asymptote.

see: http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/GUI.html#GUI

Comment: I tried `xasy` before asking the question. Could you please explain how it is equivalent to `KtikZ/QtikZ`?

Comment: Maybe you could expand on what type of equivalence you're looking for?  Your response about the asymptote interactive mode seemed to suggest you were looking for a more graphical interface. Otherwise,  simply open your `myfig.asy` file in your text editor of choice and repeatedly call "input myfig" from interactive drawing mode as you update your code.

Comment: I looking for automatic save/preview whenever I stop typing. A window in the left where I insert the code, and one in the right where I see the results instantaneously. No need for switching focus over multiple disconnected windows on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Because Asymptote can be used inside TeX with `asymptote` or `asypictureB` package, any solution in [Is there any way to get real-time compilation for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633/250119) would trivially work here.

Example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{}
    unitsize(1cm);
    settings.outformat="pdf";
    draw("Hello world", (0, 0)--(1, 1));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd recommend putting `settings.outformat="pdf";` (alternatively put in `asyheader` block) in order to speed things up, because otherwise output format would be `eps` and LaTeX would have to manually convert it to PDF. Letting Asymptote output PDF directly is faster.

---

That having said, passing through a layer of TeX and/or latexmk consumes some extra time. So, normally I open `vim a.asy`, and run a script such as

```bash
echo a.asy | entr asy -f pdf a.asy
```

in a separate terminal for automatically recompiling on changes (make sure the terminal is visible so that you can read the error messages, if any), then use `zathura` or something with automatic update to view the resulting PDF.

The `a.asy` file maybe something like the following

```
settings.tex="latex";
settings.inlineimage=true;
settings.embed=true;
size(6cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(11pt));

draw("Hello world", (0, 0)--(1, 1));
```