# Drawing 3d diagrams

Tags: diagrams, 3d

I would like to use a few simple 3d diagrams in my LaTeX document. They primarily consist of polyline segments in 3d, along with an occasional simple surface (e.g. paraboloid). There are two questions:

1) Is there a good way to draw polylines in 3d that conveys the depth? I thought about fading based on distance from the eye, and also of shadows of the drawing on the coordinate planes, but I am not sure how well it'd work in practice. I'd love hear how others solved this/see some examples that I can imitate.

2) What are the drawing packages that are compatible with LaTeX that would make the task of drawing easier. I know of [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) which can draw parametric 3d surfaces, but are there others?

Comment: Is there a picture somewhere showing what you want to achieve?  I'm afraid that I don't understand what a "polyline segment" is (my lamentable ignorance, I know).

Comment: I mention a 3d extension to Metapost in [an answer to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus/453#453).

Comment: @Andrew: I mean a sequence of line segments so that beginning of one is joined to the end of the other. Alternatively: a sequence of points joined by line segments

Comment: I'd still like to see a picture of what you would consider a "true" depiction of a 3D line drawing ...

Comment: A surface made of sequences of points joined by line segments is also known as a mesh surface.

Comment: Concerning 1), the only way I know is to use stereo pairs--pairs of 3d pictures from slightly different perspectives placed next to each other, such that if you focus your eyes behind or in front of the paper, you see a third, three-dimensional version. (You may be familiar with the "magic eye" pictures; it's the same principle.) Speaking for myself, I was never able to visualize the twisted cubic even when I had interactive images I could rotate at will; but I finally understood what it looked like after realizing it as a stereo pair.

Answer (score 13):

Asymptote is definitely a tool to look at, it can do nut just parametric surfaces, but graphs of functions, and I believe even isosurfaces, although I am not sure.

Take a look at [sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/). It does not seem to be great at surfaces, though.

Metapost can do pretty interesting things, take a look at [these examples](http://melusine.eu.org/lab/bmp/a_mp-solid/).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this doesn't answer your specific question, but nowadays, the standard answer concerning graphics seems to be: Use TikZ. See [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/) for some 3d examples.

Comment: Thanks. I do know of TikZ, and do use it occasionally. However, it is a 2D package: it cannot render surfaces other than balls, one needs to calcule all the projections by hand, etc.

Comment: @Boris: whilst I agree that TikZ has some severe limitations for drawing 3D pictures, calculating the projections by hand is not one of them.  You can specify coordinates in 3D and draw some very obviously 3D pictures - take a look at my contributions on texample.net to see some, or look at the "how to draw a torus" question on this site.

Comment: @Andrew: Your example of "smooth map" at texample.net is really cool!

Answer (score 7):

Please, consider also the more elaborated package for 3D called [pst-solides3d](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pst-solides3d.html) offering perspective features. I also recommand to visit [syracuse](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-solides3d/animations/) for more examples [website in French]

Answer (score 7):

the task to draw "a sequence of points joined by line segments" or occasionally a surface (rendered with a colormap or a shading) can be realized by means of pgfplots. Perhaps the examples in the manual (available on the sourceforge link below) or directly on the webpage http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/ can be used to decide if it does what you want, it is quite powerful.

Best regards

Christian

Comment: Very nice package!  I'll put that high up on my "to look at" list.

Comment: This looks very good!

Answer (score 6):

I wonder why nobody has mentioned [pst-3dplot](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot) or [tikZ-3dplot](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot) so far. The [tikZ Example Gallery for 3D objects](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/) contains some interesting examples (e. g. »Seismic focal mechanism«, »Spherical polar plots«, …).

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Since I already know TikZ, learning tikz-3dplot would be relatively easy.

Comment: I did post the link to the 3d example gallery in my answer ...