# How to draw an Icosahedron?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

After going through the [`pgf manual`](http://texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) and also searching the web for some solution or at least a hint on how it can be done (preferably using TikZ), so I came here with my question:

> How to draw an Icosahedron?

This is what I have in mind:

[image: Icosahedron]

Comment: You can see at
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/drawing-polyhedra-using-tikz-with-semi-transparent-and-shading-effect

Comment: See also: [3d axis and polyhedron with line segment towards origin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68247/3d-axis-and-polyhedron-with-line-segment-towards-origin)

Comment: You can find the coordinates of the vertices here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: Quoting @AndrewStacey from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/drawing-3d-diagrams: whilst I agree that TikZ has some severe limitations for drawing 3D pictures, calculating the projections by hand is not one of them. You can specify coordinates in 3D and draw some very obviously 3D pictures - take a look at my contributions on texample.net to see some, or look at the "how to draw a torus" question on this site. – Andrew Stacey Oct 30 '10 at 11:05

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-platon}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\Gobble#1{}

\begin{document}
\psIcosahedron
\psIcosahedron[Frame=false,Viewpoint=-1 0.5 1.2,faceName=\arabic]
\psIcosahedron[Frame=false,faceName=\Gobble]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The question [on polyhedra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/drawing-polyhedra-using-tikz-with-semi-transparent-and-shading-effect) has an answer by Herbert and it uses `pst-solides3d`. It can be easily extended for the present case by just replacing `octahedron` by `icosahedron`:

```
%% Code by Herbert --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17208/11232
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2)(2.5,2.5)
\psset{lightsrc=10 20 30,viewpoint=30 10 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=40}
 \psSolid[object=icosahedron,a=3,linecolor=blue,
          opacity=0.6,hollow,hue=0 1,
          action=draw**]
 \axesIIID(3,3,3)(6,4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to compile this with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}`

```
\documentclass[border=2 mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{100}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line join=round]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phi}{\a*(1+sqrt(5))/2}
    \path 
    coordinate(A) at (0,\phi,\a)
    coordinate(B) at (0,\phi,-\a)
    coordinate(C) at (0,-\phi,\a)
    coordinate(D) at (0,-\phi,-\a)
    coordinate(E) at (\a,0,\phi)
    coordinate(F) at (\a,0,-\phi)
    coordinate(G) at (-\a,0,\phi)
    coordinate(H) at (-\a,0,-\phi)
    coordinate(I) at (\phi,\a,0)
    coordinate(J) at (\phi,-\a,0)
    coordinate(K) at (-\phi,\a,0)
    coordinate(L) at (-\phi,-\a,0); 
    \draw[dashed, thick]    (B) -- (H) -- (F) 
    (D) -- (L) -- (H) --cycle 
    (K) -- (L) -- (H) --cycle
    (K) -- (L) -- (G) --cycle
    (C) -- (L) (B)--(K) (A)--(K)
    ;
        
        \draw[ultra thick]
        (A) -- (I) -- (B) --cycle 
        (F) -- (I) -- (B) --cycle 
        (F) -- (I) -- (J) --cycle
        (F) -- (D) -- (J) --cycle
        (C) -- (D) -- (J) --cycle
        (C) -- (E) -- (J) --cycle
        (I) -- (E) -- (J) --cycle
        (I) -- (E) -- (A) --cycle
        (G) -- (E) -- (A) --cycle
        (G) -- (E) -- (C) --cycle
        ; 
 %\foreach \point/\position in {A/right,B/below,C/above,D/left,E/{above right},F/below,G/above,H/left,I/below,J/right,K/below,L/left}
%{
    %\fill (\point) circle (1.5pt);
    %\node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
%}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can use `3dtools` [here](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools) to draw this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,3dtools}
\begin{document}
        \pgfdeclarelayer{background} 
    \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line cap=round,line join=round]
    \edef\lstV{{0., 0., -0.951057}, {0., 0., 0.951057}, {-0.850651, 0., -0.425325}, {0.850651, 0., 0.425325}, {0.688191, -0.5, -0.425325}, {0.688191, 0.5, -0.425325}, {-0.688191, -0.5, 0.425325}, {-0.688191, 0.5, 0.425325}, {-0.262866, -0.809017, -0.425325}, {-0.262866, 0.809017, -0.425325}, {0.262866, -0.809017, 0.425325}, {0.262866, 0.809017, 0.425325}}
    \edef\lstFaces{{2,12,8},{2,8,7},{2,7,11},{2,11,4},{2,4,12},{5,9,1},{6,5,1},{10,6,1},{3,10,1},{9,3,1},{12,10,8},{8,3,7},{7,9,11},{11,5,4},{4,6,12},{5,11,9},{6,4,5},{10,12,6},{3,8,10},{9,7,3}}
    \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,fore layer=foreground,back layer=background, 
        fore/.append style={fill opacity=0.7},back/.append style={fill opacity=0.7}}
    \begin{scope}[3d/install view={phi=120,psi=20,%
            theta=70}]
        \tikzset{name prefix=Va,%<- used for all vertices
            3d/define vertices/.expanded={\lstV},
            3d/polyhedron/create faces from vertex list/.expanded={\lstFaces}}
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{dim({\lstV})} % number of vertices
        \foreach \X in {1,...,\mydim}
        {\edef\p{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/name prefix}\X}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myp}{TD("(\p)")}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mysd}{sign(screendepth(\myp))}
            \ifnum\mysd<0
            \draw[fill=black,on layer=background] (\p) %node[above,scale=0.3]{$\p$} 
            circle[radius=0.6 pt];
            \else
            \draw[fill=black,on layer=foreground] (\p) %node[above,scale=0.3]{$\p$} 
            circle[radius=0.6 pt];
            \fi}
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]