# Truncated Icosahedron in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pst-solides3d

I would like to draw the Archimedean solid Truncated Icosahedron (soccer ball, Bucky ball), so one can use the resources on transparency, position and light source to manipulate the images.

[image]

The image on the left is executed in POVRay and sources are available at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Truncatedicosahedron.gif), the one on the right is from Mathematica and data on vertices is available with the command [PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron"]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatedIcosahedron.html).

### Listing Vertices, Edges and Faces

The vertices are all even permutations of:

```
(0, ±1, ±3ϕ)
(±2, ±(1+2ϕ), ±ϕ)
(±1, ±(2+ϕ), ±2ϕ)
```

where `$\phi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$` is the golden mean, for an explicit list see Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron#Cartesian_coordinates) or [here](http://www.scienceu.com/geometry/facts/solids/coords/tr_icosa.html).

The number of vertices (60), edges (90) and faces (32) seem a bit too large to be dealt by hand as in other examples like drawing an [Octahedron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/drawing-polyhedra-using-tikz-with-semi-transparent-and-shading-effect). All edges in this configuration have length 2 so an easy algorithm can determine the edges (the 3 neighbours at distance < 2.1). Given two edges at a vertex it is also (algorithmically) easy to find the third that compose a face -- it is the one that makes a zero-volume with the previous two vectors. How easy it is to implement all of that in TikZ? May be getting a ready set of coordinates edges and faces would be much easier?

### Cutting the Vertices of a pre-defined Icosahedron

Another possible construction would be cutting off the vertices of an (pre-defined) icosahedron in a way, so that every edge has the same length. Several packages ([pst-solids3d](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/drawing-polyhedra-using-tikz-with-semi-transparent-and-shading-effect), [pst-platon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88760/how-to-draw-an-icosahedron)) have the Icosahedron pre-define with one-command -- the issue here will the execution of the cut-offs.

In this particular case the solid is centred at the origin and all planes (that cut-off) are perpendicular to the vectors defining the original icosahedron, and equidistant to the origin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start with the skeleton. Coordinates are copy from `polyhedron_js.asy`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\foreach\s in{2,4,...,360}{
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{2.71828+\s}{2.71828+\s*2}
    \tikz[tdplot_main_coords,scale=.1]{
        \path(-150cm,-150cm)(150cm,150cm);
        \draw
            (20.1774,0,-97.9432)--(40.3548,-32.6477,-85.4729)--(73.0026,-20.1774,-65.2955)--(73.0026,20.1774,-65.2955)--(40.3548,32.6477,-85.4729)--cycle
            (20.1774,0,97.9432)--(40.3548,32.6477,85.4729)--(73.0026,20.1774,65.2955)--(73.0026,-20.1774,65.2955)--(40.3548,-32.6477,85.4729)--cycle
            (-20.1774,0,97.9432)--(-40.3548,-32.6477,85.4729)--(-73.0026,-20.1774,65.2955)--(-73.0026,20.1774,65.2955)--(-40.3548,32.6477,85.4729)--cycle
            (-20.1774,0,-97.9432)--(-40.3548,32.6477,-85.4729)--(-73.0026,20.1774,-65.2955)--(-73.0026,-20.1774,-65.2955)--(-40.3548,-32.6477,-85.4729)--cycle
            (97.9432,20.1774,0)--(85.4729,40.3548,32.6477)--(65.2955,73.0026,20.1774)--(65.2955,73.0026,-20.1774)--(85.4729,40.3548,-32.6477)--cycle
            (0,97.9432,20.1774)--(32.6477,85.4729,40.3548)--(20.1774,65.2955,73.0026)--(-20.1774,65.2955,73.0026)--(-32.6477,85.4729,40.3548)--cycle
            (-97.9432,20.1774,0)--(-85.4729,40.3548,-32.6477)--(-65.2955,73.0026,-20.1774)--(-65.2955,73.0026,20.1774)--(-85.4729,40.3548,32.6477)--cycle
            (0,97.9432,-20.1774)--(-32.6477,85.4729,-40.3548)--(-20.1774,65.2955,-73.0026)--(20.1774,65.2955,-73.0026)--(32.6477,85.4729,-40.3548)--cycle
            (-97.9432,-20.1774,0)--(-85.4729,-40.3548,32.6477)--(-65.2955,-73.0026,20.1774)--(-65.2955,-73.0026,-20.1774)--(-85.4729,-40.3548,-32.6477)--cycle
            (0,-97.9432,-20.1774)--(32.6477,-85.4729,-40.3548)--(20.1774,-65.2955,-73.0026)--(-20.1774,-65.2955,-73.0026)--(-32.6477,-85.4729,-40.3548)--cycle
            (97.9432,-20.1774,0)--(85.4729,-40.3548,-32.6477)--(65.2955,-73.0026,-20.1774)--(65.2955,-73.0026,20.1774)--(85.4729,-40.3548,32.6477)--cycle
            (0,-97.9432,20.1774)--(-32.6477,-85.4729,40.3548)--(-20.1774,-65.2955,73.0026)--(20.1774,-65.2955,73.0026)--(32.6477,-85.4729,40.3548)--cycle
            (85.4729,40.3548,-32.6477)--(97.9432,20.1774,0)--(97.9432,-20.1774,0)--(85.4729,-40.3548,-32.6477)--(73.0026,-20.1774,-65.2955)--(73.0026,20.1774,-65.2955)--cycle
            (85.4729,-40.3548,32.6477)--(97.9432,-20.1774,0)--(97.9432,20.1774,0)--(85.4729,40.3548,32.6477)--(73.0026,20.1774,65.2955)--(73.0026,-20.1774,65.2955)--cycle
            (-85.4729,40.3548,32.6477)--(-97.9432,20.1774,0)--(-97.9432,-20.1774,0)--(-85.4729,-40.3548,32.6477)--(-73.0026,-20.1774,65.2955)--(-73.0026,20.1774,65.2955)--cycle
            (-85.4729,-40.3548,-32.6477)--(-97.9432,-20.1774,0)--(-97.9432,20.1774,0)--(-85.4729,40.3548,-32.6477)--(-73.0026,20.1774,-65.2955)--(-73.0026,-20.1774,-65.2955)--cycle
            (40.3548,32.6477,-85.4729)--(20.1774,0,-97.9432)--(-20.1774,0,-97.9432)--(-40.3548,32.6477,-85.4729)--(-20.1774,65.2955,-73.0026)--(20.1774,65.2955,-73.0026)--cycle
            (-40.3548,-32.6477,-85.4729)--(-20.1774,0,-97.9432)--(20.1774,0,-97.9432)--(40.3548,-32.6477,-85.4729)--(20.1774,-65.2955,-73.0026)--(-20.1774,-65.2955,-73.0026)--cycle
            (40.3548,-32.6477,85.4729)--(20.1774,0,97.9432)--(-20.1774,0,97.9432)--(-40.3548,-32.6477,85.4729)--(-20.1774,-65.2955,73.0026)--(20.1774,-65.2955,73.0026)--cycle
            (-40.3548,32.6477,85.4729)--(-20.1774,0,97.9432)--(20.1774,0,97.9432)--(40.3548,32.6477,85.4729)--(20.1774,65.2955,73.0026)--(-20.1774,65.2955,73.0026)--cycle
            (32.6477,85.4729,-40.3548)--(0,97.9432,-20.1774)--(0,97.9432,20.1774)--(32.6477,85.4729,40.3548)--(65.2955,73.0026,20.1774)--(65.2955,73.0026,-20.1774)--cycle
            (-32.6477,85.4729,40.3548)--(0,97.9432,20.1774)--(0,97.9432,-20.1774)--(-32.6477,85.4729,-40.3548)--(-65.2955,73.0026,-20.1774)--(-65.2955,73.0026,20.1774)--cycle
            (-32.6477,-85.4729,-40.3548)--(0,-97.9432,-20.1774)--(0,-97.9432,20.1774)--(-32.6477,-85.4729,40.3548)--(-65.2955,-73.0026,20.1774)--(-65.2955,-73.0026,-20.1774)--cycle
            (32.6477,-85.4729,40.3548)--(0,-97.9432,20.1774)--(0,-97.9432,-20.1774)--(32.6477,-85.4729,-40.3548)--(65.2955,-73.0026,-20.1774)--(65.2955,-73.0026,20.1774)--cycle
            (20.1774,65.2955,-73.0026)--(32.6477,85.4729,-40.3548)--(65.2955,73.0026,-20.1774)--(85.4729,40.3548,-32.6477)--(73.0026,20.1774,-65.2955)--(40.3548,32.6477,-85.4729)--cycle
            (85.4729,40.3548,32.6477)--(73.0026,20.1774,65.2955)--(40.3548,32.6477,85.4729)--(20.1774,65.2955,73.0026)--(32.6477,85.4729,40.3548)--(65.2955,73.0026,20.1774)--cycle
            (-73.0026,20.1774,65.2955)--(-40.3548,32.6477,85.4729)--(-20.1774,65.2955,73.0026)--(-32.6477,85.4729,40.3548)--(-65.2955,73.0026,20.1774)--(-85.4729,40.3548,32.6477)--cycle
            (-85.4729,40.3548,-32.6477)--(-65.2955,73.0026,-20.1774)--(-32.6477,85.4729,-40.3548)--(-20.1774,65.2955,-73.0026)--(-40.3548,32.6477,-85.4729)--(-73.0026,20.1774,-65.2955)--cycle
            (-85.4729,-40.3548,32.6477)--(-65.2955,-73.0026,20.1774)--(-32.6477,-85.4729,40.3548)--(-20.1774,-65.2955,73.0026)--(-40.3548,-32.6477,85.4729)--(-73.0026,-20.1774,65.2955)--cycle
            (-20.1774,-65.2955,-73.0026)--(-32.6477,-85.4729,-40.3548)--(-65.2955,-73.0026,-20.1774)--(-85.4729,-40.3548,-32.6477)--(-73.0026,-20.1774,-65.2955)--(-40.3548,-32.6477,-85.4729)--cycle
            (85.4729,-40.3548,-32.6477)--(65.2955,-73.0026,-20.1774)--(32.6477,-85.4729,-40.3548)--(20.1774,-65.2955,-73.0026)--(40.3548,-32.6477,-85.4729)--(73.0026,-20.1774,-65.2955)--cycle
            (20.1774,-65.2955,73.0026)--(32.6477,-85.4729,40.3548)--(65.2955,-73.0026,20.1774)--(85.4729,-40.3548,32.6477)--(73.0026,-20.1774,65.2955)--(40.3548,-32.6477,85.4729)--cycle;
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Even has the pentagons separated from the hexagons so it can be coloured differently... and the rotation gives it a way to choose a nice position (viewing angle).

Answer (score 2):

I started with some code from [a post about icosahedron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88760/how-to-draw-an-icosahedron).

Result image is quite good. The pentagons are small. Adjust the code to get what you want. Result image is [image: here].

See the code attached.

```
\documentclass[border=2 mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} %NEED TO CALCULATE NEW POINTS
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0.1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{1-\b}

\newcommand{\pentagon}[6]{
\filldraw[fill=gray,draw=black] 
($\c*(#1)+\b*(#2)$)--
($\c*(#1)+\b*(#3)$)--
($\c*(#1)+\b*(#4)$)--
($\c*(#1)+\b*(#5)$)--
($\c*(#1)+\b*(#6)$)--cycle;
}
\newcommand{\hexagon}[4]{
\draw[#4]
($\c*(#1)+\b*(#2)$)--
($\b*(#1)+\c*(#2)$)--
($\c*(#2)+\b*(#3)$)--
($\b*(#2)+\c*(#3)$)--
($\c*(#3)+\b*(#1)$)--
($\b*(#3)+\c*(#1)$)--cycle;
}



\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{100}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line join=round]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phi}{\a*(1+sqrt(5))/2}
    \path 
    coordinate(A) at (0,\phi,\a)
    coordinate(B) at (0,\phi,-\a)
    coordinate(C) at (0,-\phi,\a)
    coordinate(D) at (0,-\phi,-\a)
    coordinate(E) at (\a,0,\phi)
    coordinate(F) at (\a,0,-\phi)
    coordinate(G) at (-\a,0,\phi)
    coordinate(H) at (-\a,0,-\phi)
    coordinate(I) at (\phi,\a,0)
    coordinate(J) at (\phi,-\a,0)
    coordinate(K) at (-\phi,\a,0)
    coordinate(L) at (-\phi,-\a,0);
    %MORE POINTS
    %G-CEAKL "TOP" 
    \hexagon{G}{C}{E}{}
    \hexagon{G}{E}{A}{}
    \hexagon{G}{A}{K}{dotted}
    \hexagon{G}{K}{L}{dotted}
    \hexagon{G}{L}{C}{dotted}
    %F-IJDHB "BOTTOM"
    \hexagon{F}{I}{J}{}
    \hexagon{F}{J}{D}{}
    \hexagon{F}{D}{H}{dotted}
    \hexagon{F}{H}{B}{dotted}
    \hexagon{F}{B}{I}{}
    %CJEIABKHLD "STRIP"
    \hexagon{C}{J}{E}{}
    \hexagon{J}{E}{I}{}
    \hexagon{E}{I}{A}{}
    \hexagon{I}{A}{B}{}
    \hexagon{A}{B}{K}{dotted}
    \hexagon{B}{K}{H}{dotted}
    \hexagon{K}{H}{L}{dotted}
    \hexagon{H}{L}{D}{dotted}
    \hexagon{L}{D}{C}{dotted}
    \hexagon{D}{C}{J}{}
    %A-BKGEI
    %B-AIFKH
    %K-ABHLG
    %G-AKLCE
    %E-AGCJK
    %I-AEJFB
    %D-CLHFJ
    %C-DJEGL
    %L-DHKGC
    %H-DFBKL
    %F-DHBIJ
    %J-DFHLC
    \pentagon{A}{B}{K}{G}{E}{I}
    \pentagon{B}{A}{I}{F}{K}{H}
    \pentagon{C}{D}{J}{E}{G}{L}
    \pentagon{D}{C}{L}{H}{F}{J}
    \pentagon{E}{A}{G}{C}{J}{I}
    \pentagon{F}{D}{H}{B}{I}{J}
    \pentagon{G}{A}{K}{L}{C}{E}
    \pentagon{H}{D}{F}{B}{K}{L}
    \pentagon{I}{A}{E}{J}{F}{B}
    \pentagon{J}{D}{F}{I}{E}{C}
    \pentagon{K}{A}{B}{H}{L}{G}
    \pentagon{L}{D}{H}{K}{G}{C}
    
    
    \path[dashed, thick]    (B) -- (H) -- (F) 
    (D) -- (L) -- (H) --cycle 
    (K) -- (L) -- (H) --cycle
    (K) -- (L) -- (G) --cycle
    (C) -- (L) (B)--(K) (A)--(K)
    ;

        \path[ultra thick]
        (A) -- (I) -- (B) --cycle 
        (F) -- (I) -- (B) --cycle 
        (F) -- (I) -- (J) --cycle
        (F) -- (D) -- (J) --cycle
        (C) -- (D) -- (J) --cycle
        (C) -- (E) -- (J) --cycle
        (I) -- (E) -- (J) --cycle
        (I) -- (E) -- (A) --cycle
        (G) -- (E) -- (A) --cycle
        (G) -- (E) -- (C) --cycle
        ; 
% \foreach \point/\position in {A/right,B/below,C/above,D/left,E/{above right},F/below,G/above,H/left,I/below,J/right,K/below,L/left}
%{
%    \fill (\point) circle (1.5pt);
%    \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
%}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know how to put the whole code nicely. It looks awful. Feel free to edit, someone.

Comment: To put the code in the right environment, just select your LaTeX code and click on the icon displaying `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

A bit with the unofficial Asymptote package [polyhedron_js.asy](https://github.com/pivaldi/asymptote-packages/blob/master/polyhedron_js.asy).

Compile with `asy -f png -render=8 <name>.asy`

```
import polyhedron_js;

currentprojection=orthographic(1,1,.5);
currentlight=Viewport;
size(7cm);

int numberofframes=72;
string[] files;

// Optional arguments and "normal" is always coincide with orthographic (1,1,.5)
path3 boundingbox = circle((0,0,0), r=1.01, normal=(1,1,.5)); 


for (int j=0; j<numberofframes; ++j)
{
  files[j]="T"+(string) j;
  picture pic;
  draw(pic, boundingbox,invisible);
  draw(pic,rotate(-j*5,Z)*surface(truncIcos),lightgreen+opacity(.7));
  draw(pic,rotate(-j*5,Z)*truncIcos,1bp+red);
  add(pic);
  shipout(files[j],bbox(invisible));
  erase();
}
```

[image]

Using https://ezgif.com/pdf-to-gif to get the gif file with the dimensions *400 x 400*

```
import polyhedron_js;
currentprojection=orthographic(1,1,.5);
currentlight=Viewport;
size(7cm);

draw(surface(truncIcos),lightgreen+opacity(.7));
draw(truncIcos,1bp+red);
shipout(bbox(invisible));
```

[image]