# How to export my math equation to be displayed in a video?

Tags: export, video

I'm working in a math video using the kdenlive editor. I was fine just using the title clip options and the unicode characters. But when the equation becomes a little bit complex for example an overbrace it becomes hard to achieve and maintain. My question then is, it is possible to use LaTeX syntax for displaying math equations in a video?

I tried use a SVG image from a internet generator, but when export the file to kdenlive it looks cutre.

Comment: Does `cutre` mean low quality? If so, could you perhaps export the LaTex equation as a PNG image that has an appropriate resolution w.r.t. the video? E.g. for a fullscreen equation on a full HD video that would be 1920x1080 pixels.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean by cutre. Well, I give a try with PNG, I was skeptical because as I understand the svg image is a vector one so it should not loss quality when import and resize in another program, but it fails. So I suppose the PNG image will be worst.

Comment: SVG *is* a vector format, but as far as I understand kdenlive (and other video editors) use raster graphics, so your SVG is converted to a raster image before it's included in your video. This conversion can happy in a sub-optimal way, so it's better to do it yourself beforehand into the right size. I never used kdenlive, so it's all rather speculation, so that's why I don't post this as an answer.

Comment: I see... but your help is very important. The PNG image format looks better that SVG in kdenlive, still is not the quality I would like. I guess I will continue using the title clip options and the unicode that's the quality that I'm happy with.

Comment: This is more of a  ideo question anyway, so perhaps you can go to video stackexchange to pose it there. They might know better how to display crisp png images in kdenlive.

Comment: That's right. I'll do that. Thank you.

Comment: The only way I know to make videos involve standalone (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295585/cube-in-tikz-not-drawn-correctly-possibly-a-bug-in-tikz).