Recreating an animated diagram (stock price gains vs. time)

"Do-it-for-me" trigger warning! :)
This question is based on a chat on this site between me and user cis, see here.
I was wondering if it is feasible to recreate a type of animated diagram that I saw on YouTube, see also GIF animation at the end of this question.
User cis offered help if I provide the raw data...this is why I created this question.


\documentclass{article} % later standalone?

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Date;Tesla_Dollar;TMC_Dollar;Tesla_Percent;TMC_Percent
2023-05-12;177.38;144.85;0.00;0.00
2023-05-15;169.76;142.41;-4.30;-1.68
2023-05-16;169.52;141.72;-4.43;-2.16
2023-05-17;174.50;142.18;-1.62;-1.84
2023-05-18;177.06;142.76;-0.18;-1.44
2023-05-19;181.95;142.44;2.58;-1.66
2023-05-22;189.32;141.71;6.73;-2.17
2023-05-23;192.96;140.32;8.78;-3.13
2023-05-24;184.22;140.38;3.86;-3.09
2023-05-25;186.78;139.98;5.30;-3.36
2023-05-26;198.60;140.44;11.96;-3.04
2023-05-30;204.48;139.56;15.28;-3.65
2023-05-31;203.95;136.57;14.98;-5.72
2023-06-01;209.80;140.86;18.28;-2.75
2023-06-02;217.25;146.39;22.48;1.06
2023-06-05;221.29;146.45;24.75;1.10
2023-06-06;221.91;148.79;25.10;2.72
2023-06-07;230.83;146.03;30.13;0.81
2023-06-08;235.23;147.00;32.61;1.48
2023-06-09;252.42;149.14;42.30;2.96
2023-06-12;250.97;149.88;41.49;3.47
2023-06-13;259.68;159.10;46.40;9.84
2023-06-14;261.57;166.48;47.46;14.93
2023-06-15;258.95;169.07;45.99;16.72
2023-06-16;263.60;166.15;48.61;14.70
2023-06-20;274.75;159.00;54.89;9.77
2023-06-21;276.99;157.34;56.16;8.62
2023-06-22;265.00;157.79;49.40;8.93
2023-06-23;262.45;154.02;47.96;6.33
2023-06-26;258.37;155.62;45.66;7.44
2023-06-27;250.39;157.21;41.16;8.53
2023-06-28;259.88;160.60;46.51;10.87
2023-06-29;260.74;160.62;47.00;10.89
2023-06-30;264.45;161.21;49.09;11.29
2023-07-03;284.25;161.57;60.25;11.54
2023-07-05;283.85;162.31;60.02;12.05
2023-07-06;279.97;161.20;57.84;11.29
2023-07-07;280.78;162.97;58.29;12.51
2023-07-10;277.52;160.40;56.46;10.74
2023-07-11;270.90;158.55;52.72;9.46
2023-07-12;276.52;160.31;55.89;10.67
2023-07-13;279.45;160.90;57.54;11.08
2023-07-14;285.30;160.00;60.84;10.46
2023-07-17;292.23;159.59;64.75;10.18
2023-07-18;295.26;163.53;66.46;12.90
2023-07-19;299.29;164.98;68.73;13.90
2023-07-20;280.93;163.64;58.38;12.97
2023-07-21;268.00;163.68;51.09;13.00
2023-07-24;269.85;164.92;52.13;13.86
2023-07-25;272.90;165.80;53.85;14.46
2023-07-26;268.04;166.02;51.11;14.62
2023-07-27;269.13;166.73;51.73;15.11
2023-07-28;267.25;167.80;50.67;15.84
2023-07-31;269.08;168.57;51.70;16.38
2023-08-01;266.47;172.36;50.23;18.99
2023-08-02;259.52;175.37;46.31;21.07
2023-08-03;260.49;168.70;46.85;16.47
2023-08-04;264.77;172.41;49.27;19.03
2023-08-07;253.65;173.39;43.00;19.70
2023-08-08;250.92;170.35;41.46;17.60
2023-08-09;251.10;168.36;41.56;16.23
2023-08-10;251.80;169.72;41.96;17.17
2023-08-11;243.79;167.64;37.44;15.73
2023-08-14;240.66;167.10;35.67;15.36
2023-08-15;240.50;165.93;35.58;14.55
2023-08-16;233.97;163.92;31.90;13.17
2023-08-17;226.74;164.01;27.83;13.23
2023-08-18;217.58;162.20;22.66;11.98
2023-08-21;232.13;163.21;30.87;12.68
2023-08-22;240.82;166.44;35.77;14.91
2023-08-23;238.98;166.08;34.73;14.66
2023-08-24;238.92;165.03;34.69;13.93
2023-08-25;239.00;165.11;34.74;13.99
2023-08-28;244.38;167.36;37.77;15.54
2023-08-29;257.48;167.59;45.16;15.70
2023-08-30;260.51;168.78;46.87;16.52
2023-08-31;261.18;172.50;47.24;19.09
2023-09-01;259.08;173.91;46.06;20.06
2023-09-05;258.00;175.84;45.45;21.39
2023-09-06;255.39;179.88;43.98;24.18
2023-09-07;252.81;179.19;42.52;23.71
2023-09-08;256.52;177.53;44.62;22.56
2023-09-11;274.85;179.12;54.95;23.66
2023-09-12;278.39;181.86;56.95;25.55
2023-09-13;274.98;184.35;55.02;27.27
2023-09-14;276.71;188.05;56.00;29.82
2023-09-15;278.98;190.86;57.28;31.76
2023-09-18;271.44;189.05;53.03;30.51
2023-09-19;267.85;195.65;51.00;35.07
2023-09-20;273.93;192.52;54.43;32.91
2023-09-21;260.86;187.32;47.06;29.32
2023-09-22;257.79;189.15;45.33;30.58
2023-09-25;247.10;185.27;39.31;27.90
2023-09-26;249.55;182.70;40.69;26.13
2023-09-27;245.33;184.42;38.31;27.32
2023-09-28;247.55;182.87;39.56;26.25
2023-09-29;254.77;181.15;43.63;25.06
2023-10-02;254.28;179.60;43.35;23.99
2023-10-03;250.02;174.43;40.95;20.42
2023-10-04;261.86;170.19;47.63;17.49
2023-10-05;263.60;174.36;48.61;20.37
2023-10-06;261.65;173.70;47.51;19.92
2023-10-09;261.36;174.17;47.34;20.24
2023-10-10;268.94;177.51;51.62;22.55
2023-10-11;268.60;178.57;51.43;23.28
2023-10-12;265.41;182.96;49.63;26.31
2023-10-13;259.60;179.47;46.35;23.90
2023-10-16;255.40;179.62;43.98;24.00
2023-10-17;257.18;179.68;44.99;24.05
2023-10-18;254.63;177.75;43.55;22.71
2023-10-19;230.61;176.88;30.01;22.11
2023-10-20;218.86;174.80;23.38;20.68
2023-10-23;216.98;175.05;22.32;20.85
2023-10-24;222.05;174.50;25.18;20.47
2023-10-25;220.10;176.88;24.08;22.11
2023-10-26;214.80;173.56;21.10;19.82
2023-10-27;212.41;175.49;19.75;21.15
2023-10-30;210.88;172.93;18.89;19.39
2023-10-31;202.80;175.22;14.33;20.97
2023-11-01;205.99;186.35;16.13;28.65
2023-11-02;219.20;186.72;23.58;28.91
2023-11-03;226.37;189.87;27.62;31.08
2023-11-06;226.32;190.56;27.59;31.56
2023-11-07;223.12;189.62;25.79;30.91
2023-11-08;224.15;184.82;26.37;27.59
2023-11-09;220.80;186.94;24.48;29.06
2023-11-10;215.38;187.10;21.42;29.17
2023-11-13;225.40;188.00;27.07;29.79
2023-11-14;238.14;192.11;34.25;32.63
2023-11-15;246.70;190.46;39.08;31.49
2023-11-16;240.88;190.82;35.80;31.74
2023-11-17;237.39;193.43;33.83;33.54
2023-11-20;237.10;188.53;33.67;30.16
2023-11-21;243.62;185.39;37.34;27.99
2023-11-22;244.01;184.59;37.56;27.44
2023-11-24;238.75;188.50;34.60;30.13
2023-11-27;238.33;186.96;34.36;29.07
2023-11-28;247.00;187.32;39.25;29.32
2023-11-29;252.75;191.24;42.49;32.03
2023-11-30;245.22;190.00;38.25;31.17
2023-12-01;240.19;192.81;35.41;33.11
2023-12-04;239.37;189.11;34.95;30.56
2023-12-05;246.66;188.98;39.06;30.47
2023-12-06;246.57;192.90;39.01;33.17
2023-12-07;244.08;190.76;37.60;31.69
2023-12-08;245.27;187.59;38.27;29.51
2023-12-11;243.44;187.71;37.24;29.59
2023-12-12;238.99;185.21;34.73;27.86
2023-12-13;240.30;186.29;35.47;28.61
2023-12-14;253.88;184.77;43.13;27.56
2023-12-15;254.13;183.04;43.27;26.37
2023-12-18;258.74;184.19;45.87;27.16
2023-12-19;258.34;185.10;45.64;27.79
2023-12-20;259.84;182.54;46.49;26.02
2023-12-21;254.80;181.24;43.65;25.12
2023-12-22;258.22;179.24;45.57;23.74
2023-12-26;257.97;180.37;45.43;24.52
2023-12-27;263.34;181.11;48.46;25.03
2023-12-28;265.13;181.69;49.47;25.43
2023-12-29;255.19;183.88;43.87;26.95
2024-01-02;251.25;182.90;41.65;26.27
2024-01-03;245.68;182.47;38.50;25.97
2024-01-04;242.70;184.20;36.82;27.17
2024-01-05;240.12;188.71;35.37;30.28
2024-01-08;241.25;188.16;36.01;29.90
2024-01-09;238.96;186.66;34.72;28.86
2024-01-10;235.50;192.81;32.77;33.11
2024-01-11;230.93;196.48;30.19;35.64
2024-01-12;225.34;195.98;27.04;35.30
2024-01-16;223.49;196.50;26.00;35.66
2024-01-17;215.67;194.39;21.59;34.20
2024-01-18;217.45;200.27;22.59;38.26
2024-01-19;213.19;200.70;20.19;38.56
2024-01-22;217.80;201.95;22.79;39.42
2024-01-23;215.65;202.00;21.58;39.45
2024-01-24;212.73;201.68;19.93;39.23
2024-01-25;193.00;200.73;8.81;38.58
2024-01-26;186.78;198.21;5.30;36.84
2024-01-29;191.48;201.85;7.95;39.35
2024-01-30;196.36;202.41;10.70;39.74
2024-01-31;193.97;202.35;9.35;39.70
2024-02-01;189.88;202.35;7.05;39.70
2024-02-02;188.69;202.64;6.38;39.90
2024-02-05;184.68;203.18;4.12;40.27
2024-02-06;186.49;221.77;5.14;53.10
2024-02-07;189.79;224.02;7.00;54.66
2024-02-08;191.62;226.40;8.03;56.30
2024-02-09;194.12;225.14;9.44;55.43
2024-02-12;194.73;226.87;9.78;56.62
2024-02-13;187.26;232.56;5.57;60.55
2024-02-14;188.89;227.16;6.49;56.82
2024-02-15;200.88;228.64;13.25;57.85
2024-02-16;203.17;228.54;14.54;57.78
2024-02-20;198.60;228.46;11.96;57.72
2024-02-21;199.44;227.66;12.44;57.17
2024-02-22;198.32;235.15;11.81;62.34
2024-02-23;197.57;235.76;11.38;62.76
2024-02-26;201.78;238.78;13.76;64.85
2024-02-27;205.60;238.84;15.91;64.89
2024-02-28;205.30;238.19;15.74;64.44
2024-02-29;205.28;241.66;15.73;66.83
2024-03-01;204.52;246.54;15.30;70.20
2024-03-04;199.75;244.79;12.61;69.00
2024-03-05;184.59;249.99;4.06;72.59
2024-03-06;181.58;253.43;2.37;74.96
2024-03-07;180.04;248.05;1.50;71.25
2024-03-08;182.73;245.80;3.02;69.69
2024-03-11;182.87;237.41;3.10;63.90
2024-03-12;179.43;238.44;1.16;64.61
2024-03-13;176.05;233.54;-0.75;61.23
2024-03-14;171.17;233.36;-3.50;61.10
2024-03-15;165.18;235.12;-6.88;62.32
2024-03-18;174.72;238.83;-1.50;64.88
2024-03-19;172.82;245.09;-2.57;69.20
2024-03-20;176.25;246.80;-0.64;70.38
2024-03-21;178.18;251.79;0.45;73.83
2024-03-22;171.20;255.23;-3.48;76.20
2024-03-25;175.24;253.42;-1.21;74.95
2024-03-26;184.25;254.79;3.87;75.90
2024-03-27;181.91;254.20;2.55;75.49
2024-03-28;179.57;252.85;1.23;74.56
2024-04-01;176.75;242.86;-0.36;67.66
2024-04-02;167.69;240.24;-5.46;65.85
2024-04-03;168.82;242.45;-4.83;67.38
2024-04-04;177.19;243.67;-0.11;68.22
2024-04-05;170.86;241.83;-3.68;66.95
2024-04-08;174.50;245.84;-1.62;69.72
2024-04-09;179.22;248.47;1.04;71.54
2024-04-10;174.93;246.12;-1.38;69.91
2024-04-11;175.88;247.15;-0.85;70.62
2024-04-12;173.81;245.27;-2.01;69.33
2024-04-15;170.69;246.07;-3.77;69.88
2024-04-16;158.19;237.37;-10.82;63.87
2024-04-17;158.33;235.29;-10.74;62.44
2024-04-18;152.20;234.11;-14.20;61.62
2024-04-19;150.94;229.79;-14.91;58.64
2024-04-22;144.44;231.15;-18.57;59.58
2024-04-23;147.26;230.64;-16.98;59.23
2024-04-24;167.97;233.99;-5.30;61.54
2024-04-25;170.88;225.49;-3.66;55.67
2024-04-26;172.12;226.98;-2.97;56.70
2024-04-29;198.87;228.45;12.12;57.71
2024-04-30;190.95;229.94;7.65;58.74
2024-05-01;185.86;228.84;4.78;57.98
2024-05-02;184.60;231.41;4.07;59.76
2024-05-03;184.78;233.35;4.17;61.10
2024-05-06;187.56;235.68;5.74;62.71
2024-05-07;183.26;233.28;3.31;61.05
2024-05-08;176.06;232.43;-0.74;60.46
2024-05-09;175.62;228.03;-0.99;57.42
2024-05-10;173.06;221.06;-2.44;52.61
\end{filecontents*}
% Data is based on 
%   https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TM/history
%   https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history


\begin{document}

Test.

\end{document}



Use standalone [tikz] and create many many pgfplots with increasing ranges, then convert the PDFs into an animation.  I've never actually done the latter, but  you can google it.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295585/cube-in-tikz-not-drawn-correctly-possibly-a-bug-in-tikz

For some of these values I get:

PS: For pdf ---> gif, I used the page 
https://ezgif.com/pdf-to-gif 
You can also use ImageMagick, if you search for the command.
PPS: For gif ---> mp4, if needed, I recommend ffmpeg. 
The command is something like this
ffmpeg -i in.gif out.mp4
\documentclass[border=5pt, 
multi=my,% language change 1/3
]{standalone}

\usepackage[german]{babel}% language change 2a/3
\usepackage[german]{translator}% language change 2b/3

\usepackage{fontawesome}% for \faCar

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=true, col sep=semicolon]{
Date;   TeslaDollar;   TMCDollar;   TeslaPercent;  TMCPercent
2023-05-12;177.38;144.85;0.00;0.00
2023-05-15;169.76;142.41;-4.30;-1.68
2023-05-16;169.52;141.72;-4.43;-2.16
2023-05-17;174.50;142.18;-1.62;-1.84
2023-05-18;177.06;142.76;-0.18;-1.44
2023-05-19;181.95;142.44;2.58;-1.66
2023-05-22;189.32;141.71;6.73;-2.17
2023-05-23;192.96;140.32;8.78;-3.13
2023-05-24;184.22;140.38;3.86;-3.09
2023-05-25;186.78;139.98;5.30;-3.36
2023-05-26;198.60;140.44;11.96;-3.04
2023-05-30;204.48;139.56;15.28;-3.65
2023-05-31;203.95;136.57;14.98;-5.72
2023-06-01;209.80;140.86;18.28;-2.75
2023-06-02;217.25;146.39;22.48;1.06
2023-06-05;221.29;146.45;24.75;1.10
2023-06-06;221.91;148.79;25.10;2.72
2023-06-07;230.83;146.03;30.13;0.81
2023-06-08;235.23;147.00;32.61;1.48
2023-06-09;252.42;149.14;42.30;2.96
2023-06-12;250.97;149.88;41.49;3.47
2023-06-13;259.68;159.10;46.40;9.84
2023-06-14;261.57;166.48;47.46;14.93
2023-06-15;258.95;169.07;45.99;16.72
2023-06-16;263.60;166.15;48.61;14.70
2023-06-20;274.75;159.00;54.89;9.77
}{\mytable}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\RowIndexMax{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{Date}\of{\mytable}
\xdef\Xmin{\pgfplotsretval}% fix 

\pgfplotsset{width=21cm, height=7cm, }

\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{D44B5D}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{0672A0}
\begin{document}

% For the 'blackwhite style' ==========
\pagecolor{black}
\tikzset{text=white}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={draw=white}}
% ============================= 



\foreach \Row in {1,...,\RowIndexMax}{%%  \RowIndexMax
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\Row}{Date}\of{\mytable}
\xdef\Xmax{\pgfplotsretval}
%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\Row}{TeslaPercent}\of{\mytable}
\xdef\teslapercent{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\Row}{TMCPercent}\of{\mytable}
\xdef\tmcpercent{\pgfplotsretval}
%
\begin{my}% language change 3a/3
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
]
% Plots =======================
\begin{axis}[
name=mygraph, 
% Plott settings =================
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
xticklabel={  \day \\ {\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\month}}  },
xticklabel style={  anchor=near xticklabel, align=center,  },
xmin=\Xmin,% fix 
xmax=\Xmax,% variable
% Diagram Style  =================
axis lines=center, 
axis line style={-},
title={\faicon{car}~  Tesla vs. Toyota},
title style={at={(0,1)}, anchor=west, 
font=\sffamily\Huge\bfseries, yshift=3em
},
%xtick distance=5mm,
]
\addplot[myred, ultra thick] table[x=Date, y=TeslaPercent] {\mytable}; 
\addplot[myred, ultra thick, only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=black}, 
nodes near coords style={anchor=west, align=left, font=\sffamily\normalsize},
nodes near coords={Tesla \\ \teslapercent\%},
] coordinates {(\Xmax,\teslapercent) }; 

\addplot[myblue, ultra thick] table[x=Date, y=TMCPercent] {\mytable}; 
\addplot[myblue, ultra thick, only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=black}, 
nodes near coords style={anchor=west, align=left, font=\sffamily\normalsize},
nodes near coords={Toyota \\ \tmcpercent\%},
] coordinates {(\Xmax,\tmcpercent) }; 
\end{axis}
%
% Show the exact date speratly ================
\begin{axis}[ 
date coordinates in=x,
xmin=\Xmin,  xmax=\Xmax,
ymin=0, ymax=1, % avoid warning 'empty range'
xtick=data,
xtickmin=\Xmax, %xtickmax=\Xmax, 
xticklabel pos=top, 
xticklabel={\phantom{0} },
extra x ticks=\Xmax,
extra x tick labels={\day.  \pgfcalendarmonthname{\month}  \year },
x tick label style={  anchor=south east, font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries,
 yshift=0.5em},
hide y axis,
x axis line style={draw=none},
xtick style={draw=none},
nodes near coords,
]
\end{axis}
% ==================================

%  Equal width due to 'nodes near coords' 
%  and negative numbers on the y-axis: 
\path[draw=none] ([xshift=-10mm]mygraph.north west) -- ([xshift=15mm]mygraph.north east); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{my}% language change 3b/3
}%% end foreach %%


\end{document}


Wow, thanks a lot! I wait a bit before accepting ...maybe another crazy user wants to give it a try :). I will upvote some other posts of you in the meantime.

Don't vote too much... They have a bot here that recognizes a "vote series" and deletes the votes again.

Ah, didn't know that. Thanks for the hint.
