Wonderful animations on a YouTube channel made with LaTeX
I have discovered a YouTube channel,
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJflS1UnbcNchcaqn3oOk5g
that publishes truly fascinating videos in which mathematical concepts are explained through spectacular animations.
Example a screenshot: 
I've noticed that many of these animations seem to be created using LaTeX code, but the visual quality and the movement of the formulas and equations go far beyond simple static LaTeX compositions.
I was wondering how these animations are created. Is it possible that advanced LaTeX-based tools are used to achieve these smooth, real-time animations, or is there some other approach, such as the use of artificial intelligence to automatically generate these types of content? Furthermore, what software or frameworks are used to integrate LaTeX with real-time animations?
If anyone has experience or knowledge of how these videos are made, I would love to learn more! What specific techniques and tools might be used to create these types of mathematical animations?
Thank you in advance for any explanation!

Interesting question! The graphic provided reminds me of the Manim videos by 3blue1brown.

I saw the title and thought you were going to ask about https://vimeo.com/1038963018

LaTeX can generate animations by putting one image per page for many pages.  Other software is needed to convert the PDF to an animaiton (google it).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295585/cube-in-tikz-not-drawn-correctly-possibly-a-bug-in-tikz for example.

@JohnKormylo Thank you very much also to David for your precious contribute.

No idea about animations in general,  nor these videos in particular, but (1) scalable vectorial graphics (SVG) can draw too nice plots because they are vectorial and scalable. (2) SVG can be animated (no idea about it, sorry),  and (3) Inkscape can include LaTeX in an SVG with the TeXText extension (in a Linux Debian, simply apt install inkscape-textext).

@Fran Thank you very much and happy christmas.

The videos were likely created using the Manim Community library, which is powered by Python.

Installation dependencies
Manim requires a recent version of Python (3.8 or above) and ffmpeg in order to work.
LaTeX is not required for the Manim library to function, but it is a valuable addition, allowing for enhanced formatting and mathematical typesetting within the text.
You can find additional details on the installation page.
Create your first animation
After installation, visit the Tutorial & Guides page to get started.
from manim import *

class HelloWorld(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("Hello world", font_size=144)  # Creates the text object
        self.play(Write(text), run_time=2)  # Animates the text drawing itself, with a 2-second duration
        self.wait(1)  # Adds a pause between animation cycles

# Don't remove the command below for the run button to work
%manim -qm -v WARNING HelloWorld

To view the result, visit this page, push the "Make Interactive", copy the code, paste it, and enjoy the magic unfold!
More content
How I animate 3Blue1Brown | A Manim demo with Ben Sparks

"Piiiii che bello . Thank you very very much. IMHO there are a lot of work to create these videos.

Definitely a lot of work, but the result is definitely worth it!

This analysis https://www.phind.com/search?cache=gd0wllq2vuw46l2hqfwm89tp suggests a host of tools. Find sources (perhaps) there, too.
As always with AI: no guarantee, what sounds good is also correct. But it gives a few pointers.

which tools were used to create the complex videos on https://www.youtube.com/@ClearMath1/videos ?


ANSWER | PHIND INSTANT MODEL

To answer this question about the tools used to create the complex videos on Clear Math's YouTube channel (@ClearMath1), I'll need to analyze the content and production quality of their videos. Based on my observation, here are some insights:

Video Analysis
The videos on Clear Math's channel feature high-quality animations, mathematical visualizations, and educational content. This suggests the use of specialized software for creating these visuals.

Likely Tools Used
Based on the complexity and quality of the videos, some likely tools used could be:

Blender - An open-source 3D creation suite that can be used for creating complex animations and visualizations.

Processing - A programming language and environment used for visual arts, especially for creating animations and interactive graphics.

Mathematica or Matplotlib - Software packages commonly used for scientific computing and data visualization, which could be employed for generating mathematical plots and graphs.

Adobe After Effects - A professional video editing software often used for motion graphics and visual effects.

OpenCV - An open-source computer vision library that could be utilized for image processing and analysis in some videos.

Python libraries like NumPy, SciPy, and Pandas - These are frequently used for numerical computations and data manipulation in scientific and educational content creation.

Custom scripts and algorithms - Given the mathematical nature of the content, it's likely that custom scripts were developed to generate specific visualizations.


Key Points to Consider

The channel focuses on explaining complex mathematical concepts, suggesting the use of tools that can accurately represent these concepts visually.
The high production quality indicates the use of professional-grade software, possibly combined with custom coding solutions.
Some videos may involve a combination of pre-rendered animations and live-action footage, requiring multiple tools for post-production work.
It's important to note that without direct confirmation from the creators, we can't be certain about all the tools used. However, based on the content and quality of their videos, these are the most probable tools involved in creating the complex visuals and animations seen on Clear Math's YouTube channel.

P.S.: Some links
Most of the programs given are easy to find. These two may be harder, so here's what wikipedia provides:

OpenCV
Processing


Thank you very very much also for you and my sincere happy Christmas.

Same to you  Sounds like long days ahead … ;)
