# How to draw an icosahedron with triangulated faces

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pst-solides3d

I would like to draw something like this by using TikZ. Here I have found several answers on how to draw such a Platonic solid but no one has the faces divided like this. I do not really care about colours. What really matters to me is to draw such icosahedron as an origami like the picture below. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88760/how-to-draw-an-icosahedron) I've found a way fro drawing an icosahedron but without subdivision of the faces.

How can I do?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The shapes that each face is divided into are definitely not triangles.

Comment: If you're drawing in 3D with coordinates, it should not be very difficult to find the faces centres and the edges middles.

Comment: @HenriMenke you’re right, the title is kinda misleading. For any face, a “kite” shape is the union of two triangles. So if I find a way to draw 6 right-angle triangles in each face then I can color them to obtain somewhat like in the picture.

Comment: @SebGlav where I can learn how to use 3D coordinates?

Comment: Actually no because the faces are not triangulated or divided in 3 “kites” as in the picture.

Comment: I see the question was closed.  However, the cited duplicate, in my mind, does not address the issue of subdivided facets.  If you also believe the cited duplicate does not answer your question, reply to me, and I will vote to reopen the question.  If the cited duplicate provided you enough information to proceed, we will let things sit.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks for the comment. Indeed the cited duplicated doesn’t help me. I mean, I saw that post and but as you said it doesn’t address of subdivided faces.

Comment: I suggest you upvote {click the up arrow) next to my prior comment, so that readers will see it as the question loads.

Comment: I can't help with tikz, but the title might be improved, e.g., "... icosahedron with each face divided into three equal parts".

Comment: @ínideOut What is the name of polyhedron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the needed points in each triangle with the `calc` library: they are the midpoint of each edge and the centroid of the triangles. Then you can make a macro to draw a triangle with those divisions.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,perspective}

\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{1A5960}
\definecolor{color2}{HTML}{B7DAB9}
\definecolor{color3}{HTML}{AE5689}

\newcommand{\mytriangle}[4] % 3 poiints, 'shadow' opacity
{
  \coordinate (center) at ($1/3*(#1)+1/3*(#2)+1/3*(#3)$);
  \coordinate (m12)    at ($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$);
  \coordinate (m13)    at ($(#1)!0.5!(#3)$);
  \coordinate (m23)    at ($(#2)!0.5!(#3)$);
  \draw[fill=color1] (center) -- (m12) -- (#1) -- (m13) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=color2] (center) -- (m12) -- (#2) -- (m23) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=color3] (center) -- (m13) -- (#3) -- (m23) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,fill=black,fill opacity=#4]  (#1) -- (#2)  -- (#3) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,3d view={40}{35}]
% Dimensiones
\pgfmathsetmacro\ph{(1+sqrt(5))/2} % golden ratio
\pgfmathsetmacro\ed{3}             % edge   (half)
\pgfmathsetmacro\hh{\ed*\ph}       % height (half)
% Vértices
\coordinate (A1) at ( \hh,-\ed,  0);
\coordinate (B1) at ( \hh, \ed,  0);
\coordinate (C1) at (-\hh, \ed,  0);
\coordinate (D1) at (-\hh,-\ed,  0);
\coordinate (A2) at ( \ed,  0,-\hh);
\coordinate (B2) at (-\ed,  0,-\hh);
\coordinate (C2) at (-\ed,  0, \hh);
\coordinate (D2) at ( \ed,  0, \hh);
\coordinate (A3) at (  0, \hh,-\ed);
\coordinate (B3) at (  0, \hh, \ed);
\coordinate (C3) at (  0,-\hh, \ed);
\coordinate (D3) at (  0,-\hh,-\ed);
% Faces
\mytriangle{A2}{A1}{D3}{0.4};
\mytriangle{A1}{B1}{A2}{0.5};
\mytriangle{D1}{C3}{D3}{0.2};
\mytriangle{A1}{D3}{C3}{0.3};
\mytriangle{C3}{D2}{A1}{0.0};
\mytriangle{B1}{A1}{D2}{0.1};
\mytriangle{D2}{B3}{B1}{0.3};
\mytriangle{C2}{D1}{C3}{0.2};
\mytriangle{D2}{C3}{C2}{0.1};
\mytriangle{B3}{C2}{D2}{0.2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!