# How to draw a coffee cup

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote

Topologists need to explain that coffee cups are homeomorphic to donuts. There are nice ways to draw donuts. So far, my best attempt is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=gray!10] (-2,0) arc (180:360:2cm);
\shade[left color=gray!10, right color=gray!80] (-2,0) arc (180:540:2cm and 1cm);
\fill[top color=gray!50,bottom color=gray!80] (1.8,-.45) arc (135:225:.35cm) arc (45:-150:.35cm) arc (90:270:.25cm) arc (-90:45:.85cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: coffee cup]

Comment: It looks like a cup to me.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter if it is a coffee cup or a tea cup. It should just be recognizable immediately as whatever sort of cup it is, and be homeomorphic to a donut.

Comment: It looks good to me. Maybe insert a black board around the ellipsis.

Comment: @Sigur I suppose what Benjamin wants is a more realistic output, like a real cup not only the idea of a cup.

Comment: Drawing donuts is relatively easy. Hence it only remains to find homeomorphism from a donut onto a cup. ;-)

Comment: Donut.........?

Comment: related: [How to draw a torus](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus)

Comment: slightly off-topic: but the wonderful coffee4 package will help you visualizing the results of having the cup too close to you LaTeX files...

Comment: I don't see the difference between this and the question that cmhughes linked to so I'm going to vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Oh, no! The question is still an open problem. After closing it will not be homeomorphic to the present version.

Comment: For reasons unknown, this question makes me hungry. `:)`

Comment: For physical models: http://www.shapeways.com/product/6CJQ9GXWW/topology-joke?optionId=55529735

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just a small addition to the growing number of cups on this page:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!100]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Saucer
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
    \fill [black!87.5, path fading=fade out] 
      (0,-2/8) ellipse [x radius=6/4, y radius=3/4];
    \shade [left color=gray!20, right color=gray!80] 
      (0,0) ++(180:1.25) arc (180:360:5/4 and 5/8+1/16);
    \shade [left color=gray!40, right color=gray!20] 
      (0,0) ellipse [x radius=5/4, y radius=5/8];
    \shade [right color=gray!40, left color=gray!20] 
      (0,0) ellipse [x radius=5/4/2, y radius=5/8/2];
    \shade [left color=gray!40, right color=gray!20] 
      (0,-1/16) ellipse [x radius=5/4/2-1/16, y radius=5/8/2-1/16];
\end{scope} 

% Handle
\begin{scope}[shift=(10:7/8), rotate=-30, yslant=1/2, xslant=-1/8]
  \shade [top color=gray!80, bottom color=gray!30] 
    (0,0) arc (130:-100:3/8 and 1/2) -- ++(0,1/4) arc (-100:130:1/8 and 1/4) -- cycle;
  \shade [top color=gray!10, bottom color=gray!60] 
    (0,0) arc (130:-100:3/8 and 1/2) -- ++(0,1/32) arc (-100:130:1/4 and 1/3) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

% Cup
\fill [black!75, path fading=fade out] 
    (0,-1) ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=1/2];
\shade [left color=gray!60, right color=gray!30] 
  (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 5/4);
\shade [bottom color=gray, top color=gray!30, opacity=1/2]
  (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 5/4);
\shade [left color=gray!20, right color=gray!40] 
  (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=1/2];
\shade [left color=gray!40, right color=gray!20] 
  (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1-1/16, y radius=1/2-1/16];
\shade [bottom color=gray, top color=gray!10, opacity=1/2] 
  (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1-1/16, y radius=1/2-1/16];

% Coffee
\begin{scope}
\clip ellipse [x radius=1-1/16, y radius=1/2-1/16];
\fill [brown!25!black] 
  (0,-1/4) ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=3/8];
\fill [brown!50!black, path fading=fade out] 
  (0,-1/4) ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=3/8];
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And clearly I've given up on doing any "proper" work today:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0, outer color=transparent!100]


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in {white,gray,red!75!black,blue!25, purple,orange}{

\tikzset{xshift={mod(\i,2)*3cm}, yshift=-floor(\i/2)*3cm}
\colorlet{cup}{\c}

% Saucer
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1-1/16)}]
    \fill [black!87.5, path fading=fade out] 
      (0,-2/8) ellipse [x radius=6/4, y radius=3/4];
    \fill [cup, postaction={left color=black, right color=white, opacity=1/3}] 
      (0,0) ++(180:5/4) arc (180:360:5/4 and 5/8+1/16);
    \fill [cup, postaction={left color=black!50, right color=white, opacity=1/3}] 
      (0,0) ellipse [x radius=5/4, y radius=5/8];
    \fill [cup, postaction={left color=white, right color=black, opacity=1/3}]
      (0,1/16) ellipse [x radius=5/4/2, y radius=5/8/2];
    \fill [cup, postaction={left color=black, right color=white, opacity=1/3}] 
      (0,0) ellipse [x radius=5/4/2-1/16, y radius=5/8/2-1/16];
\end{scope} 

% Handle
\begin{scope}[shift=(10:7/8), rotate=-30, yslant=1/2, xslant=-1/8]
  \fill [cup, postaction={top color=black, bottom color=white, opacity=1/3}] 
    (0,0) arc (130:-100:3/8 and 1/2) -- ++(0,1/4) arc (-100:130:1/8 and 1/4) -- cycle;
  \fill [cup, postaction={top color=white, bottom color=black, opacity=1/3}] 
    (0,0) arc (130:-100:3/8 and 1/2) -- ++(0,1/32) arc (-100:130:1/4 and 1/3) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

% Cup
\fill [cup!25!black, path fading=fade out] 
    (0,-1-1/16) ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=1/3];
\fill [cup, postaction={left color=black, right color=white, opacity=1/3/2},
  postaction={bottom color=black, top color=white, opacity=1/3/2}] 
    (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 5/4);
\fill [cup, postaction={left color=white, right color=black, opacity=1/3}] 
  (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=1/2];
\fill [cup, postaction={left color=black, right color=white, opacity=1/3/2},
  postaction={bottom color=black, top color=white, opacity=1/3/2}] 
    (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1-1/16, y radius=1/2-1/16];

% Coffee
\begin{scope}
\clip ellipse [x radius=1-1/16, y radius=1/2-1/16];
\fill [brown!25!black] 
  (0,-1/4) ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=3/8];
\fill [brown!50!black, path fading=fade out] 
  (0,-1/4) ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=3/8];
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I particularly like the handle which is way superior to the other cups found on this page!

Comment: I want to see how the handle ends are fused to the cup body.

Comment: Very nice! I added your example to the [TeXample TikZ Gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/coffee-cup/). We can learn much from seeing how it's done in TikZ, even if there may be cliparts available somewhere else.

Answer (score 40):

In my opinion, it's really not worth it re-inventing the wheel when there's a [bounty of coffee cups](http://openclipart.org/search/?query=cup) already out there:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

All of the above images are open-source and can be opened/edited in [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org). Furthermore, if needed, it can be exported as-is in a variety of vectorized formats (if not downloaded in PDF from the source), or exported to TikZ using [`inkscape2tikz`](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) (never tried it though).

Comment: I could be worth when you want to compute and show transitions between coffee cup and donuts.

Answer (score 27):

How about a cut that actually transforms into a donut (more or less smoothely)?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {0,...,10}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[left color=gray!80, right color=gray!30] (-2,0-\x*0.04) -- (-2,-4+\x*0.04) arc (180:360:2 and 0.5) -- (2,0-\x*0.04) arc (360:180:2 and 0.5);
        \shade[left color=gray!60, right color=gray!20,even odd rule] (0,0-\x*0.04) circle (2 and 0.5) (0,0-\x*0.04) circle (1.8+\x*0.02 and 0.45+\x*0.005);
        \shade[left color=gray!30, right color=gray!80] (0,0-\x*0.04) circle (1.8+\x*0.02 and 0.45+\x*0.005);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (2,-0.4) arc (90:270:0.05-\x*0.005 and 0.2) arc (90:-90:0.6 and 1.2) arc (90:270:0.05-\x*0.005 and 0.2) arc (-90:90:0.8 and 1.6);
            \fill[inner color=white, outer color=gray!60] (2,-2) circle (0.8 and 1.6);
        \end{scope}
        \draw (-2.1,-4.6) rectangle (2.9,0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\foreach \x in {0,...,10}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[left color=gray!80, right color=gray!30] (-2+\x*0.36,-0.4) -- (-2+\x*0.36,-3.6) arc (180:360:2-\x*0.18 and 0.5-\x*0.05) -- (2,-0.4) arc (360:180:2-\x*0.18 and 0.5-\x*0.05);
        \shade[left color=gray!30, right color=gray!80] (0+\x*0.18,-0.4) circle (2-\x*0.18 and 0.5-\x*0.05);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (2,-0.4) -- ++(0,-0.4) arc (90:-90:0.6 and 1.2) -- ++(0,-0.4) arc (-90:90:0.8 and 1.6);
            \fill[inner color=white, outer color=gray!60] (2,-2) circle (0.8 and 1.6);
        \end{scope}
        \draw (-2.1,-4.6) rectangle (2.9,0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\foreach \x in {0,...,10}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (2,-0.4) -- ++(-0.4+\x*0.04,0) arc (90:270:\x*0.08 and 1.6) -| ++(0.4-\x*0.04,0.4) arc (270:90:\x*0.06 and 1.2);
            \fill[inner color=white, outer color=gray!60] (1.2,-0.4) rectangle ++(1.6,-3.2);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (2,-0.4) -- ++(0,-0.4) arc (90:-90:0.6 and 1.2) -- ++(0,-0.4) arc (-90:90:0.8 and 1.6);
            \fill[inner color=white, outer color=gray!60] (2,-2) circle (0.8 and 1.6);
        \end{scope}
        \draw (-2.1,-4.6) rectangle (2.9,0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\foreach \x in {0,...,10}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[inner color=white, outer color=gray!60,even odd rule] (2-\x*0.16,-2) circle (0.8+\x*0.16 and 1.6) (2-\x*0.16,-2) circle (0.6+\x*0.09 and 1.2-\x*0.02);
        \draw (-2.1,-4.6) rectangle (2.9,0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice, although it is not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 19):

This is really expanding on Werner's answer.

[image: coffee cup]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=4pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{cC6C5C4}{RGB}{198,197,196}
\definecolor{c9B9999}{RGB}{155,153,153}
\definecolor{cEBEBEB}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\definecolor{cE2E1E1}{RGB}{226,225,225}
\definecolor{cC37660}{RGB}{195,118,96}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[fill=cC6C5C4] (434.7610,355.3470) .. controls (434.8330,355.1840) and
  (434.9160,355.0280) .. (435.0060,354.8760) .. controls (430.1610,355.7890) and
  (419.1950,356.2480) .. (419.1950,356.2480) .. controls (419.1950,356.2480) and
  (359.8720,367.7830) .. (359.0480,369.7050) .. controls (358.2240,371.6270) and
  (362.8930,376.8460) .. (369.7590,379.0430) .. controls (371.7360,379.6760) and
  (375.8590,381.0100) .. (381.4600,382.1710) .. controls (382.2580,381.3470) and
  (383.4360,380.8590) .. (385.0000,381.0010) .. controls (393.6770,381.7930) and
  (402.7990,381.9730) .. (411.3610,380.1380) .. controls (415.4250,379.2670) and
  (419.5480,378.7220) .. (423.6640,378.1630) .. controls (423.9010,377.5740) and
  (424.2730,377.0450) .. (424.7990,376.6330) .. controls (426.7260,375.1190) and
  (429.2370,374.1350) .. (430.4720,371.9760) .. controls (431.6770,369.8710) and
  (432.7150,367.6620) .. (433.9490,365.5770) .. controls (433.9980,365.4950) and
  (434.0510,365.4230) .. (434.1000,365.3420) .. controls (428.4430,365.0610) and
  (428.7070,355.9080) .. (434.7610,355.3470) -- cycle;
\path[fill=c9B9999] (439.8940,313.0410) .. controls (439.4410,316.1700) and
  (437.8830,327.5880) .. (435.6440,338.7910) .. controls (438.5020,338.1150) and
  (442.3000,335.1050) .. (444.6440,329.0410) .. controls (448.8940,318.0410) and
  (446.3940,310.2910) .. (444.8940,311.2910) .. controls (444.1440,311.7910) and
  (441.8320,311.8520) .. (439.8940,313.0410) -- (439.8940,313.0410) --
  cycle(394.1430,280.5400) .. controls (402.8930,281.0400) and
  (404.8790,280.1140) .. (424.6430,284.2900) .. controls (442.3930,288.0400) and
  (441.8930,297.0400) .. (441.8930,297.0400) -- (441.8930,299.7900) .. controls
  (444.8290,298.8320) and (448.2350,299.1590) .. (450.1430,299.5400) .. controls
  (452.6430,300.0400) and (463.1430,308.7910) .. (457.3930,325.7910) .. controls
  (451.6430,342.7910) and (444.1430,349.7910) .. (436.6430,354.7910) .. controls
  (434.3390,356.3260) and (432.5070,357.5780) .. (431.0750,358.5780) .. controls
  (430.2000,362.6210) and (429.5680,365.3080) .. (429.3930,365.5410) .. controls
  (428.6430,366.5410) and (424.1430,375.0410) .. (396.8930,376.0410) .. controls
  (369.6430,377.0410) and (358.8930,371.0410) .. (355.3930,366.7910) .. controls
  (351.8930,362.5410) and (340.6430,302.0400) .. (340.8930,297.0400) .. controls
  (341.1430,292.0400) and (347.8930,287.0400) .. (358.3930,283.7900) .. controls
  (367.5340,280.9610) and (385.3930,280.0400) .. (394.1430,280.5400) --
  (394.1430,280.5400) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cEBEBEB] (370.3090,309.2830) .. controls (353.7600,307.1420) and
  (346.5490,302.1870) .. (343.4390,297.9180) .. controls (342.9600,291.7080) and
  (353.7490,286.0490) .. (366.8760,284.2900) .. controls (369.4630,283.9430) and
  (374.3920,283.3960) .. (374.3920,283.3960) -- (388.0050,282.5240) .. controls
  (388.0050,282.5240) and (393.1330,282.4410) .. (394.4630,282.5320) .. controls
  (395.7930,282.6230) and (399.6760,282.7570) .. (399.6760,282.7570) .. controls
  (399.6760,282.7570) and (415.3420,284.5460) .. (416.7500,284.7780) .. controls
  (431.0540,287.1390) and (439.0400,290.5350) .. (440.0560,297.4870) --
  (439.8670,298.8380) .. controls (437.9280,301.0720) and (435.6770,303.1010) ..
  (433.2030,304.3380) .. controls (424.9630,308.4590) and (405.4790,313.8300) ..
  (370.3090,309.2830) -- (370.3090,309.2830) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cC6C5C4] (343.4380,297.9180) .. controls (346.5480,302.1870) and
  (353.7590,307.1420) .. (370.3080,309.2830) .. controls (405.4780,313.8300) and
  (424.9620,308.4590) .. (433.2020,304.3390) .. controls (435.6760,303.1020) and
  (437.9270,301.0730) .. (439.8660,298.8390) .. controls (438.5560,308.0820) and
  (430.7960,361.7480) .. (426.6110,365.5860) .. controls (420.0190,371.6270) and
  (409.3080,374.1000) .. (388.9840,374.3730) .. controls (368.6600,374.6480) and
  (364.1210,370.3400) .. (357.4000,365.8590) .. controls (354.1050,363.6620) and
  (345.8640,316.5660) .. (343.4670,298.1920) -- (343.4380,297.9180) --
  (343.4380,297.9180) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cC6C5C4,even odd rule] (429.2200,290.6070) .. controls
  (425.8610,289.3550) and (417.8990,287.2900) .. (413.6920,286.8720) .. controls
  (411.6200,286.6650) and (402.2160,285.3330) .. (391.4220,285.2500) .. controls
  (380.3000,285.1650) and (367.7140,286.3620) .. (361.1080,288.4100) .. controls
  (354.6080,290.4250) and (344.3550,294.4520) .. (347.2380,298.4350) .. controls
  (347.6940,299.0640) and (348.6340,299.8310) .. (350.0340,300.6580) .. controls
  (353.0400,299.0340) and (358.4560,296.6780) .. (366.6230,295.0120) .. controls
  (367.1020,295.5020) and (367.7790,295.8270) .. (368.6660,295.8350) .. controls
  (373.8160,295.8780) and (380.9310,296.8800) .. (385.7810,294.1870) .. controls
  (386.0070,294.2790) and (386.2510,294.3550) .. (386.5350,294.3950) .. controls
  (389.6370,294.8240) and (392.6640,295.5840) .. (395.7740,295.9720) .. controls
  (399.0870,296.3860) and (401.5770,294.6470) .. (404.7350,294.3600) .. controls
  (405.3010,294.3080) and (405.8600,294.2900) .. (406.4160,294.2860) .. controls
  (408.3660,294.8480) and (410.2280,295.0640) .. (412.0880,294.9370) .. controls
  (416.2760,295.8640) and (420.3010,297.5530) .. (424.5350,298.5620) .. controls
  (425.5620,298.8070) and (426.4580,298.5410) .. (427.1180,298.0080) .. controls
  (427.1320,298.0130) and (427.1450,298.0190) .. (427.1590,298.0240) .. controls
  (429.4520,298.9060) and (431.3660,299.8630) .. (432.8070,300.6700) .. controls
  (438.7790,296.6600) and (434.2660,292.4890) .. (429.2200,290.6070) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cC6C5C4] (426.8860,307.9100) .. controls (426.8860,307.9100) and
  (440.7690,301.3120) .. (446.9350,301.0430) .. controls (453.2520,300.7690) and
  (457.3720,309.6950) .. (456.5470,318.4840) .. controls (455.8180,326.2610) and
  (451.3290,340.0430) .. (443.0900,347.4590) .. controls (436.6800,353.2290) and
  (422.2170,361.1910) .. (422.2170,361.1910) -- (426.6120,342.7890) .. controls
  (426.6120,342.7890) and (437.8290,343.2930) .. (442.2660,336.7480) .. controls
  (453.2520,320.5430) and (447.7590,311.4800) .. (446.3860,309.8320) .. controls
  (445.0120,308.1840) and (427.4350,316.1480) .. (427.4350,316.1480) --
  (426.8860,307.9100) -- (426.8860,307.9100) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cEBEBEB] (441.5790,303.1040) .. controls (445.8360,301.4560) and
  (447.7590,301.0440) .. (450.5050,302.6920) .. controls (453.2520,304.3400) and
  (454.9000,310.2450) .. (454.9000,310.2450) .. controls (454.9000,310.2450) and
  (451.7420,305.1640) .. (449.1320,304.3400) .. controls (446.5220,303.5160) and
  (437.3220,304.7510) .. (441.5790,303.1040) -- (441.5790,303.1040) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cEBEBEB,even odd rule] (434.4380,343.6130) .. controls
  (437.7340,341.9650) and (440.8920,339.9060) .. (443.5010,337.1600) .. controls
  (446.1100,334.4120) and (447.3460,329.3320) .. (447.3460,329.3320) .. controls
  (447.3460,329.3320) and (443.9130,340.4550) .. (440.4800,343.6130) .. controls
  (437.0470,346.7710) and (434.4380,349.6560) .. (434.0260,350.6170) .. controls
  (433.6140,351.5780) and (431.1430,345.2620) .. (434.4380,343.6130) --
  (434.4380,343.6130) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cE2E1E1] (374.1530,313.9510) .. controls (376.3500,313.9510) and
  (384.8640,313.6780) .. (393.1040,314.2260) .. controls (401.3440,314.7740) and
  (416.7240,312.0290) .. (416.7240,312.0290) .. controls (416.7240,312.0290) and
  (410.6820,334.0000) .. (410.6820,348.2830) .. controls (410.6820,362.5640) and
  (403.8160,371.6270) .. (401.6190,371.6270) .. controls (399.4220,371.6270) and
  (389.8090,374.1000) .. (387.6120,370.8030) .. controls (385.4150,367.5080) and
  (376.0770,345.5350) .. (375.5280,339.4940) .. controls (374.9770,333.4510) and
  (371.9560,313.9510) .. (374.1530,313.9510) -- (374.1530,313.9510) -- cycle;
\path[fill=c9B9999] (359.3230,374.9240) .. controls (370.5830,380.4160) and
  (404.2280,382.7500) .. (423.1780,375.1970) .. controls (433.2290,371.1910) and
  (431.4170,363.1130) .. (431.4170,363.1130) .. controls (431.4170,363.1130) and
  (434.2680,364.6930) .. (434.8510,367.0950) .. controls (435.9500,371.6260) and
  (426.1630,379.2140) .. (415.6250,380.9640) .. controls (367.6990,388.9300) and
  (348.0620,369.4300) .. (359.3230,374.9240) -- (359.3230,374.9240) -- cycle;
\path[fill=cC37660] (350.0350,300.6580) .. controls (353.2680,298.9110) and
  (359.7100,295.7890) .. (368.5220,294.6450) .. controls (377.3340,293.5010) and
  (381.6000,293.1490) .. (384.0970,293.0750) .. controls (386.5940,293.0010) and
  (388.1780,293.3240) .. (392.0060,293.0790) .. controls (395.8340,292.8340) and
  (410.6660,293.9330) .. (414.4520,294.5400) .. controls (418.2380,295.1470) and
  (423.9010,296.7690) .. (427.1610,298.0220) .. controls (429.4540,298.9040) and
  (431.3680,299.8610) .. (432.8090,300.6680) .. controls (429.1930,303.0950) and
  (421.7300,305.4620) .. (408.2100,307.2230) .. controls (378.0340,311.1540) and
  (357.4950,305.0590) .. (350.0350,300.6580) -- (350.0350,300.6580) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I started with a [free clip art coffee cup](http://www.craftyjenny.com/free-clip-art-download-coffee.html), edited it until I was happy with it (I felt the steam and saucer distracted from its topological properties), and used the inkscape plugin `inkscape2tikz`.  The resulting code is pretty indecipherable, but you get a nice coffee cup!

Also: I think I might have a hardcore procrastination problem.

Comment: From the looks of your blog I'd say it is a hardcore enthusiasm problem :)

Answer (score 16):

Just a little addition to make the border of the cup thicker and improving the lighting:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=gray!10] (-2,0) arc (180:360:2cm);
\shade[left color=gray!30, right color=gray!80] (-2,0) arc (180:540:2cm and 1cm);
\shade[left color=gray!80, right color= gray!10] (-1.8,0) arc (180:540:18mm and 8mm);
\fill[top color=gray!20,bottom color=gray!90] (1.8,-.45) arc (135:225:.35cm) arc (45:-150:.35cm) arc (90:270:.25cm) arc (-90:45:.85cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]