# Error with 3D Asymptote graphs

Tags: asymptote

Help me with 3D arc in asymptote. Thank you very much!
Code:

```
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
import three;
size(7.5cm,0);
currentprojection=perspective(20,18,8);
currentlight=light(8,10,2);

path3 p=(-1,-1,0)--(1,-1,0)--(1,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--cycle;
draw(p);
path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,1)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,1)..cycle;
draw(g,2bp+.8red);
draw(surface(g),paleblue);
dot(g,5bp+.8green);
draw((0,0,0)--normal(p),1bp+blue,Arrow3()); 
\end{asy}
```

[image]

Comment: Error is: 2 black horizontal lines appear. Can you help me?

Comment: It seems to be the "usual" black lines bug due to OpenGL/Asymptote driver pb. Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437053/bug-with-asymptote-horizontal-black-lines

Answer (score 2):

I compiled

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
import three;
size(7.5cm,0);
currentprojection=perspective(20,18,8);
currentlight=light(8,10,2);

path3 p=(-1,-1,0)--(1,-1,0)--(1,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--cycle;
draw(p);
path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,1)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,1)..cycle;
draw(g,2bp+.8red);
draw(surface(g),paleblue);
dot(g,5bp+.8green);
draw((0,0,0)--normal(p),1bp+blue,Arrow3()); 
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

with the usual chain `pdflatex`, then `asy` and again `pdflatex`, I get a flawless

[image]

However, I prefer to use `asypictureB`, and when I compile

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=pfft}
settings.outformat="pdf";
import three;
size(7.5cm,0);
currentprojection=perspective(20,18,8);
currentlight=light(8,10,2);

path3 p=(-1,-1,0)--(1,-1,0)--(1,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--cycle;
draw(p);
path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,1)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,1)..cycle;
draw(g,2bp+.8red);
draw(surface(g),paleblue);
dot(g,5bp+.8green);
draw((0,0,0)--normal(p),1bp+blue,Arrow3()); 
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape
```

I also get this result. Please check what you get with these standard methods. If you get the same, please describe in detail what you do, i.e. provide us with a complete example, which starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that allows us to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Full codes:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
import three;
size(7.5cm,0);
currentprojection=perspective(20,18,8);
currentlight=light(8,10,2);
path3 p=(-1,-1,0)--(1,-1,0)--(1,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--cycle;
draw(p);
path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,1)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,1)..cycle;
draw(g,2bp+.8red);
draw(surface(g),paleblue);
dot(g,5bp+.8green);
draw((0,0,0)--normal(p),1bp+blue,Arrow3()); 
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And error pdf:
[image]

Comment: Is this now an answer or an addendum to your question?

Comment: I still haven't fixed the bug. Maybe because of my computer's graphics card.

Comment: @LêĐìnhMẫn please see my comment (following your question) and the link. It is not an error in your asy code but a driver pb. With 'maxtile` option it is possible to obtain a picture without black line.