# Getting rid of black stripes in 3d pictures generated with asymptote

Tags: asymptote

Below is a script cribbed from the asymptote examples from the softwares homepage. I tried to generate a .png image with the script but got the output as shown below.

How can I get rid of the black stripes?! I can't seem to find anything about this in the asymptote manual. Are there any extra commandline flags I must pass while calling the asy executable?

```
import three;                                                                                    

size(400);                                                                                       

path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,0)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,0)..cycle;                                             
draw(g);                                                                                         
draw(O--Z,red+dashed,Arrow3);                                                                    
draw(((-1,-1,0)--(1,-1,0)--(1,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--cycle));                                           
dot(g,red);
```

[image]

Comment: When I compile `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=b}
<your asy code>
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}` with `PDFLaTeX -shell-escape` I do not get any black stripes.

Comment: It is a usual driver problem. Please see `maxtile` option, documentation http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/three.html#three (black stripes) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437053/bug-with-asymptote-horizontal-black-lines/437154#437154 Here the black stripes are very large !