# Without error: Black fragment in asymptote graphic

Tags: asymptote

I've just copied some `asymptote` [example code](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dwebgl/cube.asy) to test the compiling. This is my result:

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import three;

currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,2,center=true);

size(5cm);
size3(3cm,5cm,8cm);

draw(unitbox);

dot(unitbox,red);

label("$O$",(0,0,0),NW);
label("(1,0,0)",(1,0,0),S);
label("(0,1,0)",(0,1,0),E);
label("(0,0,1)",(0,0,1),Z);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

What I did

1. `pdflatex cube.tex`
2. `asy cube-1.asy`
3. `pdflatex cube.tex`

and I also tested it without LaTeX, but with the same result

1. `asy cube.asy`

There was no error or anything else. Does someone has an idea how to get things to work?

Comment: I followed your prescription and get the graphics without black square. However, I have heard (without knowing the details) that there are issues with the graphics card vs. asymptote. So what I want to say is that I think that you are doing in principle the right steps.

Comment: Thank you for looking into the problem. If you're right I have to look for an alternative to asymptote. I'll try `pst-solids3d`.

Comment: I wouldn't give up so easily, see e.g. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437154/194703) which provides you with further information and links. Maybe an expert shows up and finds a simple solution.

Comment: Actually with your help I compiled the code successfully! (See my edit.)

Comment: Glad to hear! I think it would be more appropriate to refer to the `maxtile` trick as OG's solution and to link [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437154/194703). All I did was to Google a post that looked related with the search terms `site:tex.stackexchange.com asymptote graphics card issue`. (You could also write an answer so that in the future others have better chances of finding the thread. This does not exclude the possibility that an expert adds a more detailed answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Schrödinger's cat mentioned [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437154/101831) where O.G. uses the `maxtile` trick to solve the graphic card issue. I tested it and it works:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;

import three;

currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,2,center=true);

size(5cm);
size3(3cm,5cm,8cm);

draw(unitbox);

dot(unitbox,red);

label("$O$",(0,0,0),NW);
label("(1,0,0)",(1,0,0),S);
label("(0,1,0)",(0,1,0),E);
label("(0,0,1)",(0,0,1),Z);
```

...compiling this with `asy -maxtile "(256,256)" cube.asy` results in:

[image]

Comment: With `settings.prc=false` you miss the interactive 3D object that opens on click in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @AlexG I think you can assume someone who includes the line `settings.prc=false;` does not want the interactive object unless they say otherwise.

Comment: In this case, I would guess that the image has been deliberately set up so that the labels do not cross the lines, and allowing the viewer to change the point of view would mess that up.

Comment: @CharlesStaats The original post does not rule out PRC, so my comment is justified.