# Modify stacked 3D disc example

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I saw the TIkZ example of Mark Wibrow (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/disc/). The original answer is here: [tikz stacked disks 3D](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175393/2693). I need just one disc and I can modify the height of the disc where I can also put the polar coordinates. I was able to reduce the 3 stacked discs to one and put the polar coordinates using Mark's example but can not change the height of the disc. I need to lower it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se Please edit your question to show your modified code so that people can see what you've done.  I've added a link to the original answer on the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a version of [Mark's brilliant code](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/disc/) which stores the parameters in pgf keys. The parameters are height `h`, radius `r`, aspect `aspect` and a Boolean `bottom` for the shadow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\newif\iftikzdiscisbottom
\tikzset{
  pics/.cd,
  disc/.style = {
    code = {
    \tikzset{disc/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/disc/##1}}%
    \iftikzdiscisbottom
      \foreach \i in {0,2,...,30}
        \fill [black, fill opacity = 1/60] (0,-0.1)
          ellipse [x radius = \pv{r}+\i/40, y radius = \pv{r}*\pv{aspect}+\i/60];
    \fi
      \fill (0,\pv{h})[white] ellipse [x radius = \pv{r}, y radius = \pv{r}*\pv{aspect}];
      \path [left color = black!50, right color = black!50,
        middle color = black!25] 
        (-0.975*\pv{r},0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,
            x radius=\pv{r}*0.975,y radius=\pv{r}*\pv{aspect}*0.975] -- cycle;
      \path [top color = black!25, bottom color = white] 
        (0,.05*\pv{r}*\pv{aspect}+\pv{h}) 
        ellipse [x radius = 0.975*\pv{r}, y radius = \pv{r}*\pv{aspect}*0.975];
      \path [left color = black!25, right color = black!25,
        middle color = white] (-\pv{r},\pv{h}) -- (-\pv{r},0) 
        arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,
            x radius=\pv{r},y radius=\pv{r}*\pv{aspect}]
        -- (\pv{r},\pv{h}) 
        arc[start angle=360,end angle=180,
            x radius=\pv{r},y radius=\pv{r}*\pv{aspect}];
      \foreach \r in {225,315}
        \foreach \i [evaluate = {\s=30;}] in {0,2,...,30}
          \fill [black, fill opacity = 1/50] 
            (0,\pv{h}) -- ++ (\r+\s-\i:\pv{r} and \pv{r}*\pv{aspect}) 
            -- ++(0,-\pv{h}) 
            arc[start angle=\r+\s-\i,end angle=\r-\s+\i,
            x radius = \pv{r}, y radius = \pv{r}*\pv{aspect}] 
            -- ++(0,\pv{h}) -- cycle;
      \foreach \r in {45,135}
        \foreach \i [evaluate = {\s=30;}] in {0,2,...,30}
          \fill [black, fill opacity = 1/50] 
            (0,\pv{h}) -- ++ (\r+\s-\i:\pv{r} and \pv{r}*\pv{aspect}) 
            arc[start angle=\r+\s-\i,end angle=\r-\s+\i,
            x radius = \pv{r}, y radius = \pv{r}*\pv{aspect}]  -- cycle;
    }
  },/tikz/disc/.cd,h/.initial=1.1,r/.initial=2,aspect/.initial=1/3,
  bottom/.is if=tikzdiscisbottom
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) pic {disc={h=2,bottom=true}}
 (5,0) pic {disc={h=3,r=1.5,aspect=1/4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]