# how to draw a glass of wine?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a glass of wine, as the following example.
[image]

I could only do half the Cup, missing the feet and strong color of the wine. Also need to delete the axes, to leave only the figure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[view={40}{10}]
\addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,
samples=30,domain=-1:0,y domain=0:2*pi]
({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
{sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
x);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: One never should fill a glass of wine so much!

Comment: Perhaps you can start with [how to draw a coffee cup](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145223/5764).