# Couldn't able to understand the parameter definition with / symbol like "x radius=5/4/2"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to understand the coding given in the following link [How to draw a coffee cup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145223/how-to-draw-a-coffee-cup/145325), where the ellipse's radius are defined in terms of ratio's. My doubt is, "How to interpret such ratios physically"?
I also found such ratios in bodeplot package example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer for the mathematical part of the question.

The expression `5/4/2` uses the division operator that is left associative. That means, the expression is evaluated from left to right:

> 5/4/2 = (5/4)/2 = 5/8 = 0.625

I think the author has chosen `5/4/2` over `0.625` to show a little better, how
the value is calculated. For example, a previous line contains `x radius=5/4` and `5/4/2` was used in `x radius=5/4/2`. Then, it is easier (without calculations) to see, that 5/4/2 is the half of 5/4 as that 0.625 is the half of 1.25.