# Rotation transformation of a parametrized plot

Tags: pgfplots, rotating, 3d

I'm working on this plot with pgfplots:

[image: Twisted surface]

The image is from our sister-site [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37698/) and there's also a nice explanation how to do it with Mathematica.

I follow these steps:

1. Parametrize the 2d cut
2. Embed it in 3d
3. Rotate both in a circle and around itself

I originally posted the question on the [TeXwelt LaTeX forum](http://texwelt.de/) in German, my first steps which I wrote in "[Drehtransformation mit pgfplots](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7436/drehtransformation-mit-pgfplots)" are:

1. The 2d cut:

   ```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{polaraxis}
       \addplot[mark=none, domain=0:360, samples=100] 
         {sin(3*x) + 1.25}; 
     \end{polaraxis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: 2d plot]
2. Embedding in 3d for better visualizing with some temporary filling:

   ```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
       \addplot3 [domain=0:360, samples=60, fill=blue!30, opacity=0.8]
         ( {cos(x)*(sin(3*x) + 1.25)},
           {sin(x)*(sin(3*x) + 1.25)}, 0 );
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}  
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: 2d plot embedded in 3d]

   No problem also to get a surface with simple 3d expansion:

   ```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
       \addplot3 [
           surf,
           domain    = 0:360,
           y domain  = 0:360,
           samples   = 50,
           samples y = 20,
         ]
         ( {cos(x)*(sin(3*x) + 1.25)},
           {y}, {sin(x)*(sin(3*x) + 1.25)} );
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}  
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: 3d surface plot]
3. That's my question, because I still need to bend and twist it:

   How can I rotate that 2d plot around a circle, while rotating it at the same time around its origin, to get a surface plot like in the image at the top?

Comment: There are a particular formula in the answer [below](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37715/2342). Is there are any reason not to use an equation?

Comment: @m0nhawk Yes - though a conjured up ready-to-plot but complex function is nice, I would like to learn about applying rotation transformations in 3d. It would be great if we could work out even a generic macro for it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When I saw your first picture, it immediately made me think of a torus; of course, it's a bit of a twisted torus, but it does have quite a lot in common. As detailed in [How to draw a torus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus) (for example), a torus can be parametrized as a surface using (for example)

```
x(t,s) = (2+cos(t))*cos(s+pi/2) 
y(t,s) = (2+cos(t))*sin(s+pi/2) 
z(t,s) = sin(t)
```

where `t` and `s` both lie on the interval `[0,2\pi]`.

So, how can we apply this to your shape?

Let's start by trying to plot the curve given by the following parametrization in three dimensions:

```
x(t) = sin(3t)cos(t)
y(t) = sin(3t)sin(t)
```

A little bit of thought, and application of the torus idea tells us that in your example we can use the following, for example,

```
  x(t,s) = (4+(sin(3*(t))+1.25)*cos(t))*cos(s) 
  y(t,s) = (4+(sin(3*(t))+1.25)*cos(t))*sin(s) 
  z(t,s) = ((sin(3*(t))+1.25)*sin(t))
```

Which gives, for a fixed value of `s` and `t\in[0,2\pi]`

[image: screenshot]

From here, we can allow `s` to vary - for example, if we allow `s\in[0,\pi]` then we achieve:

[image: screenshot]

This is close, but it doesn't twist enough - for that we can choose, for example

```
  x(t,s) = (4+(sin(3*(t+Ns))+1.25)*cos(t))*cos(s) 
  y(t,s) = (4+(sin(3*(t+Ns))+1.25)*cos(t))*sin(s) 
  z(t,s) = ((sin(3*(t+Ns))+1.25)*sin(t))
```

The number `N` can be changed to increase/decrease the 'twistyness'; for example with `N=10` and a fairly low resolution, then we achieve:

[image: screenshot]

Finally, you crank up the resolution as much as you can before exhausting memory (running `LuaLaTeX` really helps - thanks Stefan), and you get the following:

[image: screenshot]

This can be improved by using, for example, `shader=interp`. Here's the complete code to play with :)

```
% arara: lualatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
        ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            samples=100, samples y=70,
            colormap/cool,
            domain=0:360,y domain=0:360,
            z buffer=sort,
        ]
        ({(4+(sin(3*(x+2*y))+1.25)*cos(x))*cos(y)},
        {(4+(sin(3*(x+2*y))+1.25)*cos(x))*sin(y)},
        {((sin(3*(x+2*y))+1.25)*sin(x))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Once we have the template, we can play with it a little more; for example, changing the parametrisation from `sin(3(x+2y))` to `sin(4(x+2y))` and using the `hot2` colormap as follows

```
    \addplot3[
        surf,
        samples=100, samples y=70,
        colormap/hot2,
        domain=0:360,y domain=0:360,
        z buffer=sort,
    ]
    ({(4+(sin(4*(x+2*y))+1.25)*cos(x))*cos(y)},
    {(4+(sin(4*(x+2*y))+1.25)*cos(x))*sin(y)},
    {((sin(4*(x+2*y))+1.25)*sin(x))});
```

gives a pleasing picture with a few more twists:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very nice! Btw. the memory exhaustion can be avoided simply using LuaLaTeX. I did, and I got surprisingly different results just by changing samples y to 30 and 50.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz thanks for noting that - I believe you'll get consistent results with the updated code :)

Comment: You should consider the additional options `shader=flat, miter limit=1. The fine grid lines result in a relatively hard look which is smoothened by `shader=flat`, and `miter limit` avoids the tiny overshoots near edges.

Answer (score 1):

I can't stand drawing this [twisted torus](https://pgfplots.net/twisted-torus/) with Assymptote.

[image]

```
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(6cm);  
import graph3;
import palette;
currentprojection=orthographic(3,2,2.2,zoom=.9);

triple f(pair M) {
real t=M.x, s=M.y;
real d = 1 + sin(4t+8s);  
real a = (6+d*cos(t))*cos(s);
real b = (6+d*cos(t))*sin(s);
real c =    d*sin(t);
return (a,b,c);
}  

pen[] p=Rainbow(30);
//pen[] p=Gradient(magenta,yellow);
surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2pi,2pi),50,30,Spline);
draw(s,mean(palette(s.map(zpart),p)),black);
```

More palette can be found [here](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/palette.html).

[image]