# How we can draw the Hopf fibration

Tags: graphics, floats, draw

How we can draw the pre-image of the ***Hopf fibration*** in Tex?

For example, I mean the figure in page 73
of the prescribed  link:

http://www.personal.psu.edu/axk29/TOPOLOGY/Chapter2.pdf

[image: hopf-fibration]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://nilesjohnson.net/hopf.html

Comment: @jsbibra Wonderful animations around Hopf fibration. A thousand thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! The question [how one may draw a torus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348/194703) has many answers, out of which I choose [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485833/194703) to start. This is because it comes with a parametrization of the projection of the torus on the screen coordinates and does not require external software. If you want to mass produce 3d drawings, you may be ultimately better off with asymptote, though. Given these parametrizations, it is rather easy to draw

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tikzset{declare function={%
torusx(\u,\v,\R,\r)=cos(\u)*(\R + \r*cos(\v)); 
torusy(\u,\v,\R,\r)=(\R + \r*cos(\v))*sin(\u);
torusz(\u,\v,\R,\r)=\r*sin(\v);
vcrit1(\u,\th)=atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% first critical v value
vcrit2(\u,\th)=180+atan(tan(\th)*sin(\u));% second critical v value
thetacritA(\R,\r)=atan(sqrt(\R/\r-1));
thetacritB(\R,\r)=acos(\r/\R);
ucritA(\R,\r,\th)=180+(90/pi)*sqrt(abs(-(\R^2*pow(cot(\th),2))+4*pow(\r,2)/pow(sin(2*\th),2)))/\R; 
ucritB(\R,\r,\th)=540-ucritA(\R,\r,\th);
umaxA(\R,\r,\th)=asin(sqrt(abs(-pow(cot(\th),2)+4*pow(\r,2)/(pow((sin(2*\th)*\R),2)))));
umaxB(\R,\r,\th)=180-umaxA(\R,\r,\th);}}
\tikzset{3d torus/.style n
args={2}{/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\DDA}{int(sign(sin(thetacritA(#1,#2))-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\DDB}{int(sign(sin(thetacritB(#1,#2))-sin(\tdplotmaintheta)))},
  insert path={
  plot[variable=\x,domain=1:359,smooth cycle,samples=71]
  ({torusx(\x,vcrit1(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
 {torusy(\x,vcrit1(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
 {torusz(\x,vcrit1(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)}) 
   \ifnum\DDA=1
    plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth cycle,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)})    
   \else
   \ifnum\DDB=1 
    plot[variable=\x,domain={umaxA(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)}:{umaxB(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)},smooth,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)})    --
    plot[variable=\x,domain={180+umaxA(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)}:{180+umaxB(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)},smooth,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)})  -- cycle  
    \fi 
   \fi
  }},3d torus stretch/.style n args={2}{/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\DDA}{int(sign(thetacritA(#1,#2)-\tdplotmaintheta))},
  insert path={\ifnum\DDA=-1
   plot[variable=\x,domain={ucritA(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)}:{ucritB(#1,#2,\tdplotmaintheta)},smooth,samples=71]
    ({torusx(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusy(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)},
    {torusz(\x,vcrit2(\x,\tdplotmaintheta),#1,#2)}) 
  \fi 
}}}
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={
 rfib(\x)=3*\x/sqrt(5+\x*\x);}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusA}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusB}{1}
    \clip[tdplot_screen_coords] 
    (-\RadiusA-1.5*\RadiusB,{-(\RadiusA+1.5*\RadiusB)*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)})
    rectangle
    (\RadiusA+1.5*\RadiusB,{(\RadiusA+1.5*\RadiusB)*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)});
    \draw (0,0,{-(\RadiusA+1.3*\RadiusB)*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)}) -- (0,0,0);
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
     \foreach \X in {1.5,2.5,...,8.5}
     {\draw ({-\RadiusA+rfib(\X)},0) arc(360:180:\X) 
     ({\RadiusA-rfib(\X)},0) arc(180:360:\X);}
    \end{scope}
    \draw[thick,samples=71,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.8,even odd
    rule,3d torus={\RadiusA}{\RadiusB}] ;
    \draw[thick,samples=71,3d torus stretch={\RadiusA}{\RadiusB}];
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
     \foreach \X in {1.5,2.5,...,8.5}
     {\draw ({-\RadiusA+rfib(\X)},0) arc(0:180:\X) 
     ({\RadiusA-rfib(\X)},0) arc(180:0:\X);}
    \end{scope}
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0)-- (0,0,{(\RadiusA+1.3*\RadiusB)*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)}) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you tell me what the purpose of the curve on the torus is, I may add it, too.

I was looking for a realistic Hopf fibration and found

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFMf0.jpg

;-)

Comment: Thanks. Does this work with \documentclass[...]{book}  or \documentclass{article} ?

Comment: @314159. Yes. As long as you load `\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}` and paste the `\tikzset` stuff somewhere. (The torus functions are also part of an experimental library, see https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools, but this has not yet been polished yet to the extent that it is publishable.)

Answer (score 2):

I fully realize the OP seeks an answer in LaTeX (tikz...), but sometimes you have to realize when there is a better tool for a job.  I plotted the below in less than five minutes using *Mathematica*, with transparency, etc.... a figure that can easily be included as a .eps file in a LaTeX document.

[image]

If you have the mathematical form for the other planar curves, those can be easily added too.

---

In case anyone is interested:

```
myTorus = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[v] (2 + Cos[u]), Sin[v] (2 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]}, 
  {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  Mesh -> None,
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> None];

myCurve = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[2 t] (2 + Cos[3 t]), Sin[2 t] (2 + Cos[3 t]), Sin[3 t]},
  {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}];

Show[myTorus, myCurve]
```

Comment: I cannot run your code. There is a bug.

Comment: @minhthien_2016:  (an errant bracket... fixed).  Try it now.

Comment: G.Stork Thank you very much. Now, It works.