# Drawing a torus with critical points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to get something like this but without the plane V (So only the torus vertically and the four critical points s,r,q and p ). I don't have any experience with drawing things with Latex. Any help would be appreciated.  [image: Torus with critical points]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348/232027

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a torus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus)

Comment: I can't figure out how to draw the points on the torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roland suggested, you could use the [following solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464779/90297), and simply add points to it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (-3,-1.5) rectangle (3,1.5);
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (3 and 1.5);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,-1.8) ellipse (3 and 2.5);
    \draw (0,2.2) ellipse (3 and 2.5);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,2.2) ellipse (3 and 2.5);
    \draw (0,-2.2) ellipse (3 and 2.5);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[text=violet] (3,0) node{\Huge{.}} node[above]{A};
  \draw[text=violet] (1.4,0) node{\Huge{.}} node[above]{B};
  \draw[text=violet] (-1.4,0) node{\Huge{.}} node[above]{C};
  \draw[text=violet] (-3,0) node{\Huge{.}} node[above]{D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]